# Render XAML Image into windows phone App

Tags: xaml, windows-phone-7.1

I would like to render a XAML Image inside a Windows Phone Page.

Is it possible?

Comment: I've tried to do the same as Silverlight desktop Environment, but Drawing class, doesn't exist. I don't know any alternative. Suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can just plop it in your view, or use the same method I recently mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13292179/best-way-to-use-a-vector-image-in-wpf). Short though is yes, you can render a xaml image in your app just fine. I normally try to leave more than an answer of just a sentence or two but no need in this instance, hope this helps :)

Comment: Thanks! I will try to do it programatically.