# Error when using x:Shared="False" resources in external assembly in WPF

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, xaml, resourcedictionary

In our project we have a `ResourceDictionary` with some Icons that looks like this:

```
<ResourceDictionary
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml">

    <Canvas x:Key="Icon.Refresh"
            x:Shared="False"
            Width="32"
            Height="32"
            Clip="F1 M 0,0L 32,0L 32,32L 0,32L 0,0">
        <Path .../>
        <Path .../>
        <Path .../>
    </Canvas>
</ResourceDictionary>
```

The `x:Shared="False"` attribute is needed, because else the icon would disappear when I use it in multiple views.

Now we want to make another project with the same icons, so we decided to put them in a library project that is referenced by both projects.

But when we try to run the application we always get the error:

> Shared attribute in namespace "http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml" can be used only in compiled resource dictionaries."

but we can't get rid of the `x:Shared="False"` attribute, because as far as I know it's the only way to stop the icons from disappearing.

So we what can we do, to share the icons over multiple projects with a project reference and without disappearing icons?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Judging by this error, we can understand that `x:Shared` attribute can be used only for *compiled* `ResourceDictionary`. Quote from [`MSDN` *x:Shared Attribute*](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa970778%28v=vs.110%29.aspx):

> The `ResourceDictionary` that contains the items with `x:Shared` must be *compiled*. The ResourceDictionary cannot be within loose XAML or used for themes.

Compiled `ResourceDictionary` is one that `Build action` to set *`Page`*, as in this case, it is converted to BAML (Binary Application Markup Language) at run-time. This attribute usually be set by default when creating new `ResourceDictionary`.

`BAML` is simply XAML that has 
been parsed, tokenized, and converted into binary form to increase performance for working with XAML files. Quote from Adam Nathan WPF book:

> BAML is not like Microsoft intermediate 
>   language (MSIL); it is a compressed declarative format that is faster to load and parse (and 
>   smaller in size) than plain XAML. BAML is basically an implementation detail of the 
>   XAML compilation process.

Therefore it is always advisable to check this flag in `ResourceDictionary`, because if it will be set `Resource`, in the memory will be stored not packaged version of XAML, which later may affect to the performance of the whole WPF application.

Comment: @OmegaMan: Thanks for the edit, I just added the keyword at run-time in `it is converted to BAML (Binary Application Markup Language) at run-time. `

Comment: @OmegaMan: And you +1 for example of using `DrawingImage`.

Comment: I hesitate to edit anyone's post who has a score over 1K, but felt I could provide *value* to your post. Thank you for the +1, I knew it didn't solve the issue (like your answer does) but could provide an alternate solution.

Comment: Note from recent experience: `x:Shared` can't be placed in a nested `ResourceDictionary` inside a resource file (with correct build action). I had a case where my `ResourceDictionary` contained another dictionary with `x:Key`, which was assigned to some controls `Resources`. I had to move the `<Image x:Key="MyIcon" x:Shared="False" .../>` resource to the outer resource dictionary in order to avoid the error in question.

Answer (score 3):

Could you try setting the Build action to "Page" instead of "Resources", as mentioned here:

-https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/776631/using-x-shared-in-a-resourcedictionary-prevents-you-from-setting-the-file-build-action-to-resource

Answer (score 2):

I am not sure if I ran into something similar but this strikes a chord. The advice learned and now given is to change the container. Use a [DrawingImage](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.drawingimage%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) which will contain the multiple vectors which itself resides in the shared dictionary.

```
    <DrawingImage x:Key="diSingle">
        <DrawingImage.Drawing>
            <DrawingGroup>
                <GeometryDrawing Brush="#FF22BAFD" Geometry="F1 M 14.72,15.68L 12.38,15.68L 7.205,5.92L 7.11,5.92L 2.29,15.68L 0,15.68L 6.58,2.56L 7.595,2.56L 14.72,15.68 Z "/>
                <GeometryDrawing Brush="#FF22BAFD" Geometry="F1 M 21.585,25.6C 21.1017,25.6 20.69,25.4275 20.35,25.0825C 20.01,24.7375 19.84,24.3267 19.84,23.85C 19.84,23.37 20.01,22.955 20.35,22.605C 20.69,22.255 21.1017,22.08 21.585,22.08C 22.0783,22.08 22.4975,22.255 22.8425,22.605C 23.1875,22.955 23.36,23.37 23.36,23.85C 23.36,24.3267 23.1875,24.7375 22.8425,25.0825C 22.4975,25.4275 22.0783,25.6 21.585,25.6 Z "/>
                <GeometryDrawing Brush="#FF22BAFD" Geometry="F1 M 28.625,25.6C 28.1417,25.6 27.73,25.4275 27.39,25.0825C 27.05,24.7375 26.88,24.3267 26.88,23.85C 26.88,23.37 27.05,22.955 27.39,22.605C 27.73,22.255 28.1417,22.08 28.625,22.08C 29.1183,22.08 29.5375,22.255 29.8825,22.605C 30.2275,22.955 30.4,23.37 30.4,23.85C 30.4,24.3267 30.2275,24.7375 29.8825,25.0825C 29.5375,25.4275 29.1183,25.6 28.625,25.6 Z "/>
                <GeometryDrawing Brush="#FF22BAFD" Geometry="F1 M 35.665,25.6C 35.1817,25.6 34.77,25.4275 34.43,25.0825C 34.09,24.7375 33.92,24.3267 33.92,23.85C 33.92,23.37 34.09,22.955 34.43,22.605C 34.77,22.255 35.1817,22.08 35.665,22.08C 36.1583,22.08 36.5775,22.255 36.9225,22.605C 37.2675,22.955 37.44,23.37 37.44,23.85C 37.44,24.3267 37.2675,24.7375 36.9225,25.0825C 36.5775,25.4275 36.1583,25.6 35.665,25.6 Z "/>
                <GeometryDrawing Brush="#FF22BAFD" Geometry="F1 M 48.96,25.155L 48.96,28.48L 47.36,28.48L 47.36,25.28C 45.1267,25.28 43.3133,24.8217 41.92,23.905L 41.92,21.12C 42.5267,21.6633 43.3567,22.1192 44.41,22.4875C 45.4633,22.8558 46.4467,23.04 47.36,23.04L 47.36,15.14C 45.08,14.04 43.6033,13.0258 42.93,12.0975C 42.2567,11.1692 41.92,10.0717 41.92,8.805C 41.92,7.30167 42.4325,6.0025 43.4575,4.9075C 44.4825,3.8125 45.7833,3.15667 47.36,2.94L 47.36,9.53674e-007L 48.96,9.53674e-007L 48.96,2.88C 51.12,2.94333 52.6133,3.23333 53.44,3.75L 53.44,6.4C 52.3167,5.60667 50.8233,5.18 48.96,5.12L 48.96,13.24C 51.1733,14.27 52.6867,15.2658 53.5,16.2275C 54.3133,17.1892 54.72,18.2833 54.72,19.51C 54.72,20.9867 54.2117,22.2267 53.195,23.23C 52.1783,24.2333 50.7667,24.875 48.96,25.155 Z M 47.36,12.37L 47.36,5.215C 46.4733,5.38833 45.7717,5.76917 45.255,6.3575C 44.7383,6.94583 44.48,7.66 44.48,8.5C 44.48,9.38 44.6908,10.1017 45.1125,10.665C 45.5342,11.2283 46.2833,11.7967 47.36,12.37 Z M 48.96,15.945L 48.96,22.915C 51.0933,22.4817 52.16,21.4133 52.16,19.71C 52.16,18.29 51.0933,17.035 48.96,15.945 Z "/>
            </DrawingGroup>
        </DrawingImage.Drawing>
    </DrawingImage>
```

Then access *the image* as a [dynamic resource](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms748942%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) (bound at runtime) in a container such as this ribbon button:

```
<RibbonToggleButton x:Name="btnSingleline"
                    IsChecked="{Binding RegexOption_Single, Mode=TwoWay}"
                    Label="Single Line"
                    LargeImageSource="{DynamicResource diSingle}"
                    SmallImageSource="{DynamicResource dilines}"
                    ToolTipImageSource="{DynamicResource dilines}"/>
```

---

See my answer below for a different example using `DrawingImage`.

[Best way to use a vector image in WPF?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30854778/285795)

Answer (score 2):

For Reference:

> In WPF, `x:Shared` is only valid under the following conditions:
>
> - The ResourceDictionary that contains the items with `x:Shared` must be compiled. The ResourceDictionary cannot be within loose XAML or used
>     for themes.
> - The ResourceDictionary that contains the items must not be nested within another ResourceDictionary. For example, you cannot use
>     `x:Shared` for items in a ResourceDictionary that is within a Style that
>     is already a ResourceDictionary item.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/xaml-services/x-shared-attribute