# View can't be shared by more than one Listview

Tags: wpf, listview, styles, share

I have a problem which it seemed, many other people had before. I try to use a style, which contains a GridView by several controls.

I searched the web for answers and got two solutions:

- Change StaticResource with DynamicResource
- Use x:shared="False" on the GridView

I tried both solutions (even at the same time) but the error still appears as soon as I'm applying the style to a second control.

The style looks like this

```
<Style x:Key="MyCustomStyle" TargetType="{x:Type MyUserControl}" BasedOn="{StaticResource MyUserControlBaseStyle}">
    <Setter Property="Watermark" Value="{x:Static LabelResources.Caption}"/>
    <Setter Property="ErrorText" Value="{Binding Converter={StaticResource FormatStringConverter}, ConverterParameter={x:Static LabelResources.Caption}}"/>
    <Setter Property="LookupTemplate">
        <Setter.Value>
            <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type LookupResult}">
                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}" Margin="0,0,2,0"/>
                </StackPanel>
            </DataTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>

    <Setter Property="SuggestionsView" Value="{DynamicResource CustomGridView}"/>
</Style>
```

and here the GridView

```
<GridView x:Key="CustomGridView" x:Shared="False">
    <GridViewColumn Header="{x:Static resources:LabelResources.Name}" Width="Auto" HeaderContainerStyle="{DynamicResource GridViewHeaderStyle}">
        <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}" HorizontalAlignment="Left"/>
            </DataTemplate>
        </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
    </GridViewColumn>             
</GridView>
```

What can I do?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It sounds like you only have one single instance of `CustomGridView` created, and you are trying to assign it to multiple places, which is causing the exception.

According to the [MSDN page on x:Shared](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa970778(v=vs.110).aspx)

> In WPF, x:Shared is only valid under the following conditions:
>
> - **The ResourceDictionary that contains the items with x:Shared must be compiled**. The ResourceDictionary cannot be within loose XAML or used
>     for themes.
> - The ResourceDictionary that contains the items must not be nested within another ResourceDictionary. For example, you cannot use
>     x:Shared for items in a ResourceDictionary that is within a Style that
>     is already a ResourceDictionary item.

I'm not exactly sure what it means to be a Compiled ResourceDictionary, but you could try changing the Build Action to Page instead of Resource, like [this answer suggests](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22066727/error-when-using-xshared-false-resources-in-external-assembly-in-wpf/22070256#22070256).

If you can't get x:Shared working, then perhaps consider making `SuggestionsView` a `ContentTemplate` or `DataTemplate` instead so each use of it will create it's own GridView.

```
<ContentTemplate x:Key="CustomGridView">
    <GridView>
        <GridViewColumn Header="{x:Static resources:LabelResources.Name}" Width="Auto" HeaderContainerStyle="{DynamicResource GridViewHeaderStyle}">
            <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}" HorizontalAlignment="Left"/>
                </DataTemplate>
            </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
        </GridViewColumn>             
    </GridView>
</ContentTemplate>
```

Comment: Hi Rachel. Isn't it the purpose of the x:shared="false" to create a new instance of the GridView? SuggestionsView is basically a class derived from GridView with some extra features which allows me to add dynamically created columns.

Comment: @StefanG Yes, but it only works if the object is in a compiled ResourceDictionary. It won't work if it's loose XAML or in another nested dictionary. How is yours setup?

Comment: I have a ResourceDictionary with all my styles for this control. What do you mean with "compiled"? Is there a special option for that or is it the normal behaviour when using ResourceDictionaries?

Comment: @StefanG I think it needs to be compiled as a separate file. I'm just reading off the bottom of the [MSDN site for x:Shared](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa970778(v=vs.110).aspx) : *x:Shared is only valid under the following conditions: a) The ResourceDictionary that contains the items with x:Shared must be compiled. The ResourceDictionary cannot be within loose XAML or used for themes. b) The ResourceDictionary that contains the items must not be nested within another ResourceDictionary.*

Comment: @StefanG Perhaps verify the Build Action of the ResourceDictionary is set to Page and not Resource, as explained in this answer? http://stackoverflow.com/a/22070256/302677

Comment: That sounds interesting. I will try that tomorrow when I'm back at work and mark this as the answer if it works.

Comment: @StefanG Ok, I've updated my answer to include that information in case it does work. Good luck with it!

Comment: I checked the ResourceDictionary. Unfortunately its build action was already set to 'Page' :(. I will see if I can go with the template suggestion.

Comment: Oh I noticed that it is actually working. I wasn't aware of it at first because at design time the message still appears and the control cannot be drawn in the designer. But at runtime it works. Is there also an solution for the error being displayed at design time?

Comment: @StefanG I'm not sure, I typically just ignore all design time warnings in XAML, as long as they don't affect runtime. Did you try changing the Build Action flag and seeing if they go away?

Comment: the built action of the Resource Dictionary is already set to 'Page'. Changing it to Resource leads to compile errors