# Button ContextMenu Image only shown at last item

Tags: c#, wpf, button, contextmenu

I have a problem with a dynamic `ContextMenu` on a `Button`.

The `Button` is inside a `DataGrid` with the following Columndefinition in a ResourceDictionary:

```
<DataGridTemplateColumn Width="16" x:Key="ShowContextMenuColumn" x:Shared="False" KeyboardNavigation.IsTabStop="False">
    <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <Button Style="{StaticResource ShowContextMenuButtonStyle}">
                <Button.ContextMenu>
                    <ContextMenu ItemsSource="{Binding Data.ContextActionItems, Source={StaticResource proxy}}" DisplayMemberPath="DisplayText">
                        <ContextMenu.Resources>
                            <Style TargetType="{x:Type MenuItem}">
                                <Setter Property="Icon">
                                    <Setter.Value>
                                        <Image Source="{Binding Image}"/>
                                    </Setter.Value>
                                </Setter>
                                <Setter Property="Command" Value="{Binding Command}"/>
                            </Style>
                        </ContextMenu.Resources>
                    </ContextMenu>
                </Button.ContextMenu>
            </Button>
        </DataTemplate>
    </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
    <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellStyle>
        <Style TargetType="{markup:Type DataGridCell}" BasedOn="{StaticResource BaseDataGridCellStyle}">
            <Setter Property="AutomationProperties.Name" Value="ContextMenu"/>
        </Style>
    </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellStyle>
</DataGridTemplateColumn>
```

The `ObservableCollection<DisplayListActionItem>` for the ContextActionItems is defined in an abstract generic base-class which is inherited by several ViewModels.

The DisplayListActionItem-Class looks like:

```
public class DisplayListActionItem : NotifyBase
{
    public string DisplayText
    {
        get { return Get<string>(); }
        set { Set(value); }
    }

    public ICommand Command
    {
        get { return Get<ICommand>(); }
        set { Set(value); }
    }

    public ImageSource Image
    {
        get { return Get<ImageSource>(); }
        set { Set(value); }
    }
}
```

Everything just works fine. The only problem is, that the Image is only shown at the last item of the `ContextMenu`. If I remove the last item, then the image of the new last item is shown. I don't understand what's the reason for this.

I've already checked the Debug-Output for Binding-Errors, but there are none.

Any ideas what could cause this problem?

Comment: The linked question doesn't answer this

Comment: What happens if you set <Image> to some static image rather than binding? Ok? That would infer there is something wrong in your Get<ImageSource>()

Comment: Same. The Image is always displayed only at the last item

Comment: I think there is something called x:Shared that would help you with this.Have a look at [this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/q/22066727/2029607)

Comment: Already have `x:shared` at the ColumnDefinition. Where else should I set x:shared?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved it by myself.

The solution was to modify the ContextMenu-ItemContainerStyle instead doing the needed stuff in the Resources of the ContextMenu.

The new xaml for the Button looks like:

```
<Button Style="{StaticResource ShowContextMenuButtonStyle}">
    <Button.ContextMenu>
        <ContextMenu ItemsSource="{Binding Data.ContextActionItems, Source={StaticResource proxy}}" >
            <ContextMenu.ItemContainerStyle>
                <Style TargetType="{x:Type MenuItem}">
                    <Setter Property="Icon" Value="{Binding Image, Converter={converter:ImageSourceToImageConverter}}"/>
                    <Setter Property="Header" Value="{Binding DisplayText}"/>
                    <Setter Property="Command" Value="{Binding Command}"/>
                </Style>
            </ContextMenu.ItemContainerStyle>
        </ContextMenu>
    </Button.ContextMenu>
</Button>
```