# How to combined multiple PATH objects into a vector image that can be used as a style in WPF/XAML

Tags: wpf, xaml, path, geometry, blend

I have a complex logo developed in Illustrator that I want to use as an image in WPF.  I can seem to combine the Path's when importing into Blend to get a single Path without loosing all the fill colours.

What is the best way to convert the illustrator image into something that can be used in WPF/XAML.

Usually i just combine the Path's into a single Path and then reference the path using the following:

```
<Application.Resources>
   <Path x:Key="pathKeyName" Data="..."/>

</Application.Resources>


<Path Style="{StaticResource pathKeyName}" />
```

However there seems to be no easy way to group multiple paths together into a single image that can be used as a resource in a similar manner.

Perhaps there is a way to convert these paths into a Geometry ?

EDIT
In the meantime I have used Blend to create a UserControl from the selected paths and then I place this control inside a Viewbox - not quite as simple but it seems to work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No sweat, go grab yourself Mike Swanson's [AI to XAML exporter plugin](http://www.mikeswanson.com/xamlexport/) for Illustrator (dont pay attention to the versions mentioned on there, it works just fine with the newest version I use it all the time) and export your logo to XAML for WPF.

Then take that XAML and plop it in a `ContentControl` like I [show how on a previous SO answer post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13292179/best-way-to-use-a-vector-image-in-wpf/13293017#13293017).

Then you plop that Style Template into your resource dictionary or wherever and reference it as such with one line wherever/however you need it, voila. :)

Hope this helps, cheers.

OH PS, if there's a lot of shapes/colors etc, you'll never get it into just one Path, sorry amigo.

Comment: Awesome dude!  Thanks.  I am sure you can also tell me how I can animate the size of the image, I want it to pulse bigger and smaller by say 20%.  I keep getting and error saying property ScaleX is not found on my object (am using a PATH).  Will try it on your ContentControl.

Comment: I was just being dump - not setting the correct Storyboard.TargetProperty

Comment: Good deal, as long as you're sorted. Cheers :)