# Using control as static resource causes ArgumentException

Tags: xaml, windows-phone-8, windows-phone

For my Windows Phone 8.1 app, I'm trying to make icons available as static resources by putting them into my XAML page's `ResourceDictionary`:

```
<phone:PhoneApplicationPage.Resources>
  <ResourceDictionary>
    <Path x:Name="MyIcon" Width="38" Height="31.6667" Fill="{StaticResource PhoneForegroundBrush}" Data="..."/>
  </ResourceDictionary>
</phone:PhoneApplicationPage.Resources>
```

When I try to use `MyIcon` inside a button from code-behind...

```
Button buyButton = new Button { Content = MyIcon };
```

...an `ArgumentException` is thrown at this line: `Value does not fall within the expected range.`

When referencing `MyIcon` directly in XAML, it appears correctly in the visual editor, but causes an `XAMLParseException` while the page is loading.

Am I doing something wrong or is using control objects as static resources just not possible?

Comment: see my previous answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13292179/best-way-to-use-a-vector-image-in-wpf/13293017#13293017) it will still apply to wp, you'll just turn it into a contentcontrol.

Comment: That would be a possible workaround, but doesn't really answer the question why mine fails, but thanks anyway.

Comment: I would say because you're not calling it as a staticresource and expecting it to magically find MyIcon, but sorry amigo I'm a xaml / front-end guy so my code behind ignorance won't help you much. Hopefully someone can come teach us both something new.

Comment: @ChrisW I don't expect it to magically appear. Since above code snippet is located in the page's code-behind class, it actually **is** accessible that way, i.e. all UIElements with an `x:Name` can be addressed that way. If not, I probably would've gotten an error at compile time.

Answer (score 1):

You can't use one instance of the UIElement in few places of the visual/logical tree. So your path is currently in the tree and can't be used.
I have the same issue in last project, the my solution is a create a path by a value converter.

```
public class PathConv
    : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        var data = value as string;
        if (data == null)
        {
            return value;
        }
        return CreatePath(data);
    }

    private Path CreatePath(string pathString)
    {
        var xaml = string.Format("<Path xmlns='{0}'><Path.Data>{1}</Path.Data></Path>",
            "http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation",
            pathString);

        return XamlReader.Load(xaml) as Path;
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

Now you can create a string resource and convert it to path

```
<phone:PhoneApplicationPage.Resources>
  <ResourceDictionary>
    <PathConv x:Name="conv" />
    <String x:Key="PathData">...</String>
  </ResourceDictionary>
</phone:PhoneApplicationPage.Resources>
```

Now you can write something like this

```
Button buyButton = new Button { Content = conv.Convert(Resources["PathData"], null, null, null) };
```

Comment: Haha, that's exactly the workaround I'm using right now, except I'm hardcoding the whole path, since I need explicit height and with. :)

Comment: You can store your Paths as a string instead of a path data and construct it by the XamlReader

Comment: Yeah, but storing three strings for each path seems like an overkill to me.