# XAML SVG color change at runtime

Tags: wpf, xaml, svg

We have a set of SVGs stored within a resource dictionary.

Example:

```
<ResourceDictionary xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation" xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml">
    <DrawingImage x:Key="Bell">
        <DrawingImage.Drawing>
            <DrawingGroup Opacity="1">
                <DrawingGroup.Children>
                    <DrawingGroup Opacity="1">
                        <DrawingGroup.Children>
                            <DrawingGroup Opacity="1">
                                <DrawingGroup.Children>
                                    <GeometryDrawing Brush="#FF000000" Pen="{x:Null}">
                                        <GeometryDrawing.Geometry>
                                            <PathGeometry FillRule="Nonzero" Figures="........." />
                                        </GeometryDrawing.Geometry>
                                    </GeometryDrawing>
                                </DrawingGroup.Children>
                            </DrawingGroup>
                        </DrawingGroup.Children>
                    </DrawingGroup>
                </DrawingGroup.Children>
            </DrawingGroup>
        </DrawingImage.Drawing>
    </DrawingImage>
</ResourceDictionary>
```

If you noticed the GeometryDrawing Brush is set to #ff000000 (black).
The problem we face is allowing a view to display this SVG and assign the color at runtime (via binding)

Our Window (view) has the Resource Dictionary with the icons inside of the Window.Resources.

We are looking for a solution like so:

```
<Image Source="{StaticResource Bell}" Fill="#FF884422"/>
```

Comment: That seems like a lot of fluff, personally I just [export them](http://www.mikeswanson.com/xamlexport/) as XAML and turn them into templated ContentControl's where I can pass in all that stuff as Dependency Properties to the child elements in a one liner and store the templates in a resource dictionary.

Comment: This looks like the path I am going to take, do you have an example you can share?

Comment: Yea, I've got meetings starting in just a minute but I'll swing back to this after lunch and hook you up as soon as I get a sec.

Comment: Chris, in your templates, what are you putting inside? A PathGeometry or just Path values?

Comment: You can throw whatever you like in there, I forgot I answered a similar question [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13292179/best-way-to-use-a-vector-image-in-wpf/13293017#13293017) so you have a reference, then you can set setter's for the dependency properties you want to hit in the template as long as you're using {TemplateBinding blah} which would allow you to do something like <ContentControl Fill="Red" Stroke="Blue"/> etc, etc.

Comment: Due to comment limitations I have to break out my response into a few into two responses.

I tried the following (removed some xaml), but the {TemplateBinding Background}. Does not seem to work.

Comment: <Style x:Key="SomeStyle" TargetType="ContentControl">
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="ContentControl">
                    <Image>
                        <Image.Source>
                            <DrawingImage>
    ....
    <GeometryDrawing Brush="{TemplateBinding Background}"/>
    ....
                            </DrawingImage>
                        </Image.Source>
                    </Image>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>

Comment: How are you adding new dependency properties to the content control ? Are you creating a custom  contentcontrol that inherits and appending new properties? What if I want to bind multiple colors to this icon?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/74878/discussion-between-ealianis-and-chris-w).

Comment: Got it, you can delete, I'll email you what I wrote in chat.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By building on top of Paolo's non-working answer, I was able to solve this.

The "MyImage" class:

```
Public Class MyImage
    Inherits System.Windows.Controls.Image

    Public Property Color As System.Windows.Media.SolidColorBrush

End Class
```

Inside the resource dictionary, assign the DrawingImage to the Source setter of a MyImage style:

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type local:MyImage}" x:Key="Bell">
        <Setter Property="Source">
            <Setter.Value>
                <DrawingImage>
                    <DrawingImage.Drawing>
                        <DrawingGroup Opacity="1">
                            <DrawingGroup.Children>
                                <DrawingGroup Opacity="1">
                                    <DrawingGroup.Children>
                                        <DrawingGroup Opacity="1">
                                            <DrawingGroup.Children>
                                                <GeometryDrawing
                                                    Brush="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type local:MyImage}}, Path=Color}"
                                                    Pen="{x:Null}" />
                                            </DrawingGroup.Children>
                                        </DrawingGroup>
                                    </DrawingGroup.Children>
                                </DrawingGroup>
                            </DrawingGroup.Children>
                        </DrawingGroup>
                    </DrawingImage.Drawing>
                </DrawingImage>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
</Style>
```

Inside the window's XAML file:

```
<Window
    ...
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:AppNameHere">
    <Window.Resources>
        <ResourceDictionary Source="DictionaryName.xaml" />
    </Window.Resources>
    ....
    <Grid Background="Black">
        <local:MyImage Color="Chartreuse" Width="30" Height="30" Style="{StaticResource Bell}" />
    </Grid>
    ...
</Window>
```

Here's the result: https://i.stack.imgur.com/7JNyH.png

Answer (score 4):

Have a look at this tool:
https://github.com/BerndK/SvgToXaml

It can convert all svg's automatically to one xaml. The colors are separated and can be set for all images at once or just for a single image. Sample code for changing colors during runtime is included.

The tool is also a svg browser, viewer ...

Comment: @Joseph: the library is designed to convert an SVG to a .NET Path object. This one is by design not colored, so you can (and have to) set the color you like. This is good for single color icons used by modern designs.
If you want multi color icons, you could combine several paths (as shown in the demo of SvgToXaml), but i would consider to use png files. Doing so you might loose the advantage of  paths/geometries: scalable without quality loss.

Answer (score 1):

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication1.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApplication1"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525" >
<Window.Resources>
    <DrawingImage x:Key="Bell1">
        <DrawingImage.Drawing>
            <DrawingGroup Opacity="1">
                <DrawingGroup Opacity="1">
                    <DrawingGroup Opacity="1">
                        <GeometryDrawing  Brush="{Binding Color}" Pen="{x:Null}">
                            <GeometryDrawing.Geometry>
                                <PathGeometry FillRule="Nonzero"  Figures="M 10,100 C 10,300 300,-200 300,100" />
                            </GeometryDrawing.Geometry>
                        </GeometryDrawing>
                    </DrawingGroup>
                </DrawingGroup>
            </DrawingGroup>
        </DrawingImage.Drawing>
    </DrawingImage>
</Window.Resources>
<Grid>
    <local:MyImage DataContext="{Binding ElementName=myImage, Mode=OneWay}" x:Name="myImage"  Color="Red" Source="{StaticResource Bell1}" ></local:MyImage>

</Grid>
```

Answer (score 0):

The DrawingImage will receive the same datacontext as the window, so you can bind the color to a property on the window's view model.

Dictionary1.xaml

```
<ResourceDictionary xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation" xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml">
    <DrawingImage x:Key="Bell">
        <DrawingImage.Drawing>
            <DrawingGroup Opacity="1">
                <DrawingGroup.Children>
                    <DrawingGroup Opacity="1">
                        <DrawingGroup.Children>
                            <DrawingGroup Opacity="1">
                                <DrawingGroup.Children>
                                    <GeometryDrawing Brush="{Binding IconColor}" Pen="{x:Null}">
                                        <GeometryDrawing.Geometry>
                                            <PathGeometry FillRule="Nonzero" Figures="........." />
                                        </GeometryDrawing.Geometry>
                                    </GeometryDrawing>
                                </DrawingGroup.Children>
                            </DrawingGroup>
                        </DrawingGroup.Children>
                    </DrawingGroup>
                </DrawingGroup.Children>
            </DrawingGroup>
        </DrawingImage.Drawing>
    </DrawingImage>
</ResourceDictionary>
```

MyTestWindow.xaml

```
<Window x:Class="MyTestWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml">        
    <Window.Resources>
        <ResourceDictionary Source="Dictionary1.xaml" />
    </Window.Resources>
    <Grid>
        <Image Source="{StaticResource Bell}" />
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Then the view model will need an IconColor property.