# XAML images as StaticResources throw an error in Windows Universal app

Tags: xaml, winrt-xaml, win-universal-app, staticresource

I have some vector icons I want to use throughout my windows universal application. I've added them to a resource dictionary, added the dictionary to a merged dictionary in app.xml, and tried using the resources in a page. The images actually show up in the editor preview window, but throw an error when I attempt to debug the application.

ManaSymbols.xaml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xaml:ResourceDictionary 
    xmlns:xaml="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml">
    <Viewbox x:Key="BlueManaSymbol" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation" Stretch="Uniform">
        <Canvas Width="100" Height="100">
            <Canvas.RenderTransform>
                <TranslateTransform X="0" Y="0"/>
            </Canvas.RenderTransform>
            <Canvas>
                <Canvas>
                    <Ellipse Width="100" Height="100" Fill="#FFC1D7E9"/>
                </Canvas>
                <Path Fill="#FF0D0F0F">
                    <Path.Data>
                        M 68.91657 83.71021 C 58.968869 94.408441 39.101769 93.367284 30.985174 80.955583 23.700186 70.338629 25.060135 55.965661 30.782622 44.970201 37.43962 31.696018 47.119757 19.99635 58.53257 10.53421 c -1.779599 7.330526 -2.971221 15.369494 0.5678 22.406733 4.282692 9.098857 12.226705 16.065144 15.7407 25.557642 2.950311 8.612064 0.582748 18.823437 -5.9245 25.211625 z m -0.129 -27.362 c -0.82319 -2.47714 -5.460323 -8.506164 -4.125006 -2.813916 -0.362035 4.191263 -1.937779 8.124558 -3.178994 12.106916 -0.269255 7.254198 11.007675 4.685165 9.226 -1.795 -0.01849 -2.611632 -0.877381 -5.133602 -1.922 -7.498 z
                    </Path.Data>
                </Path>
            </Canvas>
        </Canvas>
    </Viewbox>
</xaml:ResourceDictionary>
```

App.xaml

```
<Application.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary>
        <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
            <ResourceDictionary Source="Assets/ManaSymbols.xaml"/>
        </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
    </ResourceDictionary>
</Application.Resources>
```

Page.xaml

```
<ContentControl Content="{StaticResource BlueManaSymbol}" Grid.Row="0" Margin="70,0,0,0" Width="30" Height="30" />
```

Error throw when debugging:

```
A first chance exception of type 'Windows.UI.Xaml.Markup.XamlParseException' occurred in MagicStats.Windows.exe
WinRT information: Failed to assign to property 'Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls.ContentControl.Content'. [Line: 79 Position: 25]
```

The error message seems to indicate that the binding failed, but it actually works in the design window. Any thoughts are appreciated.

Comment: That error would be expected with how you're doing it. Do it like I show [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13292179/best-way-to-use-a-vector-image-in-wpf/13293017#13293017) and you'll be good to go on anything.

Comment: Thanks so much, this worked nicely once I remembered to change Content="" to Style="". This method doesn't seem to allow scaling in the calling xaml, and instead uses the sizes defined in the template. Any suggestions?

Comment: Oh yea, there's lots you can do about that, you could set some default dimensions in the template setters, then template bind the dimensions on your in ViewBox or whatever like Width="{TemplateBinding Width}" so then at the instance you can just do `<ContentControl Style="{StaticResource blah}" Width="500"/>` or whatever you want. There's several options.