# Is there any way to affect xaml Icons with style?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, resourcedictionary, wpf-style

I've included xaml icons in my WPF application using resource dictionaries and I'm using ContentControl to render the resource icon on the window.

```
<MenuItem.Header>
       <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
              <ContentControl Content="{StaticResource appbar_database}" />
       </StackPanel>
</MenuItem.Header>
```

**Now, How can I apply style to the icon inside the ContentControl? e.g. Setting width to 24px.**

**EDIT 1**

This is how my resource dictionary looks like:

```
<ControlTemplate x:Key="appbar_database">
    <Canvas xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation" xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml" Width="76" Height="76" Clip="F1 M 0,0L 76,0L 76,76L 0,76L 0,0">
        <Path Width="34" Height="38" Canvas.Left="21" Canvas.Top="19" Stretch="Fill" Fill="#FF000000" Data="F1 M 38,19C 47.3888,19 55,21.0147 55,23.5038L 55,25.5C 55,27.9853 47.3888,30 38,30C 28.6112,30 21,27.9853 21,25.5L 21,23.5C 21,21.0147 28.6112,19 38,19 Z M 55,52.5C 55,54.9853 47.3888,57 38,57C 28.6112,57 21,54.9853 21,52.5L 21,46.5C 21,48.9853 28.6112,51 38,51C 47.384,51 54.9921,48.9874 55,46.5039L 55,52.5 Z M 55,43.5C 55,45.9853 47.3888,48 38,48C 28.6112,48 21,45.9853 21,43.5L 21,37.5C 21,39.9853 28.6112,42 38,42C 47.384,42 54.9921,39.9874 55,37.5038L 55,43.5 Z M 55,34.5C 55,36.9853 47.3888,39 38,39C 28.6112,39 21,36.9853 21,34.5L 21,28.5C 21,30.9853 28.6112,33 38,33C 47.384,33 54.9921,30.9874 55,28.5038L 55,34.5 Z "/>
    </Canvas>
</ControlTemplate>
```

Comment: Why a `ContentControl`? What is `appbar_database`? Is it a filepath? Have you tried using an `Image` control?

Comment: That's a resource reference to the ResourceDictionary file with the content above.

Comment: I'm not certain what you are asking here. The most obvious answer to your question would be to simply change the width and height of your `Path`. But I have a feeling that there's more to this. Can you please elaborate on your question? What are you seeing compared to what you want?

Comment: Yeah it's totally logical to change the width of the Path element itself. But the problem is, the Icon is going to be used in several places with different sizes. So it's not a wise choice to set width property in the element definition. I want to set the property on the window which i'm gonna use the Icon; not directly in the resource dictionary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out a previous related answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13292179/best-way-to-use-a-vector-image-in-wpf/13293017#13293017). The only difference is you're going to bind those properties to the template so you can effect them at the instance.

So for example, if you add a;

```
<Setter Property="Width" Value="34"/>
```

to the template so you establish a default for that property, and then on your Path INSIDE the template change it to;

```
Width="{TemplateBinding Width}"
```

Then...at the instance level you can put;

```
<ContentControl Style="{StaticResource YourStyleTemplateForThisThing}" Width="24"/>
```

Same applies to most properties, hope this helps. Cheers.

Comment: Thanks, This seems the only way to do it. I mean this is a very common scenario, why would it be so hard to implement in WPF?

Comment: Who says it's hard? You're just interacting with  dependency properties of an object that lives somewhere else, you'd expect to have to do a little work to cross that bridge right? Either way, glad you got a remedy. Cheers!