# WPF use Canvas as ImageSource

Tags: wpf, xaml, canvas, icons, infragistics

I am new to WPF and trying to build a basic app with a toolbar and icons. I am testing XamRibbon from Infragistics and `ButtonTool` that shows on the Ribbon require `ImageSource` to show an image like so:

```
 <igRibbon:ButtonTool Caption="Edit"
                                             igRibbon:RibbonGroup.MaximumSize="ImageAndTextLarge"
                                             LargeImage="{StaticResource stop}"
                                             SmallImage="{StaticResource stop}" />
```

I have a XAML icon defined in my dictionary with key 'stop' but the icons I am using are all in `Canvas` form like this:

```
 <Canvas Width="32" Height="32" Canvas.Left="0" Canvas.Top="0">
<Canvas Clip="M15.82,31.2118l2.0148,-3.8306l-0.0332,-0.0332l0.1068,-0.1068l0.5615,-1.0675l0.253,0.253l8.5884,-8.5885l-0.0112,-0.0111l1.6101,-1.5876c0.4557,-0.4557,0.923,-0.5523,1.234,-0.5523c0.311,0,0.7784,0.0967,1.239,0.5572l0.6169,0.6168V0H0v32h15.7137C15.656,31.7398,15.6889,31.4614,15.82,31.2118z">
  <Canvas>
    <Canvas.RenderTransform>
      <TransformGroup>
        <TranslateTransform X="-1" Y="-1"/>
      </TransformGroup>
    </Canvas.RenderTransform>
    <Polygon Points="17,28 17,24.5 15,24.5 15,28 3,28 3,30 29,30 29,28" Fill="#4EA17E" StrokeLineJoin="Miter"/>
    <Path Data="M18.475,31h-4.9c-0.3038,0,-0.575,-0.1962,-0.575,-0.5v-2.95c0,-0.3038,0.2712,-0.55,0.575,-0.55h4.9c0.3038,0,0.55,0.2462,0.55,0.55V30.5C19.025,30.8038,18.7788,31,18.475,31z" Fill="#797979"/>
    <Path Data="M28,1H4c-0.5523,0,-1,0.4477,-1,1v5c0,0.5523,0.4477,1,1,1h24c0.5523,0,1,-0.4477,1,-1V2C29,1.4477,28.5523,1,28,1zM7,6H5V3h2V6zM28,9H4c-0.5523,0,-1,0.4477,-1,1v5c0,0.5523,0.4477,1,1,1h24c0.5523,0,1,-0.4477,1,-1v-5C29,9.4477,28.5523,9,28,9zM7,14H5v-3h2V14zM28,17H4c-0.5523,0,-1,0.4477,-1,1v5c0,0.5523,0.4477,1,1,1h24c0.5523,0,1,-0.4477,1,-1v-5C29,17.4477,28.5523,17,28,17zM7,22H5v-3h2V22z" Fill="#3E79B4"/>
    <Path Data="M7,22H5v-3h2V22zM7,11H5v3h2V11zM7,3H5v3h2V3z" Fill="#FFFFFF"/>
  </Canvas>
</Canvas>
<Canvas>
  <Path Data="M19.2158,27.348l9.0199,-9.0199l2.1233,2.1233l-9.0199,9.0199L19.2158,27.348zM29.6123,16.9515c0.3525,-0.3525,0.7113,-0.3525,1.0638,0l1.0596,1.0596c0.3525,0.3525,0.3525,0.7113,0,1.0638l-0.8743,0.8743l-2.1388,-2.1202L29.6123,16.9515zM16.7052,31.677l2.0176,-3.8361l2.1233,2.1233l-3.8361,2.0176c-0.061,0.0321,-0.1358,0.0207,-0.1846,-0.028l-0.0923,-0.0923C16.6845,31.8128,16.6732,31.738,16.7052,31.677z" Fill="#3E79B4"/>
</Canvas>
```

How can I convert Canvas XAML to something that can be used as `ImageSource` like a `DrawingImage` for example? I hope this makes sense.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used the Blend for Visual studio to convert your `Canvas` as `DrawingBrush`. Now I can simply use what Blend Gave me. Only copy and paste I did.

```
<Image Height="32" Width="32">
                <Image.Source>
                    <DrawingImage>
                        <DrawingImage.Drawing>
                            <DrawingGroup>
                                <DrawingGroup ClipGeometry="M15.82,31.2118L17.8348,27.3812 17.8016,27.348 17.9084,27.2412 18.4699,26.1737 18.7229,26.4267 27.3113,17.8382 27.3001,17.8271 28.9102,16.2395C29.3659,15.7838 29.8332,15.6872 30.1442,15.6872 30.4552,15.6872 30.9226,15.7839 31.3832,16.2444L32.0001,16.8612 32.0001,0 0,0 0,32 15.7137,32C15.656,31.7398,15.6889,31.4614,15.82,31.2118z">
                                    <DrawingGroup>
                                        <DrawingGroup.Transform>
                                            <MatrixTransform Matrix="1,0,0,1,-1,-1" />
                                        </DrawingGroup.Transform>
                                        <GeometryDrawing Brush="#FF4EA17E" Geometry="M17,28 L17,24.5 15,24.5 15,28 3,28 3,30 29,30 29,28 z" />
                                        <GeometryDrawing Brush="#FF797979" Geometry="M18.475,31L13.575,31C13.2712,31,13,30.8038,13,30.5L13,27.55C13,27.2462,13.2712,27,13.575,27L18.475,27C18.7788,27,19.025,27.2462,19.025,27.55L19.025,30.5C19.025,30.8038,18.7788,31,18.475,31z" />
                                        <GeometryDrawing Brush="#FF3E79B4" Geometry="M28,1L4,1C3.4477,1,3,1.4477,3,2L3,7C3,7.5523,3.4477,8,4,8L28,8C28.5523,8,29,7.5523,29,7L29,2C29,1.4477,28.5523,1,28,1z M7,6L5,6 5,3 7,3 7,6z M28,9L4,9C3.4477,9,3,9.4477,3,10L3,15C3,15.5523,3.4477,16,4,16L28,16C28.5523,16,29,15.5523,29,15L29,10C29,9.4477,28.5523,9,28,9z M7,14L5,14 5,11 7,11 7,14z M28,17L4,17C3.4477,17,3,17.4477,3,18L3,23C3,23.5523,3.4477,24,4,24L28,24C28.5523,24,29,23.5523,29,23L29,18C29,17.4477,28.5523,17,28,17z M7,22L5,22 5,19 7,19 7,22z" />
                                        <GeometryDrawing Brush="White" Geometry="M7,22L5,22 5,19 7,19 7,22z M7,11L5,11 5,14 7,14 7,11z M7,3L5,3 5,6 7,6 7,3z" />
                                    </DrawingGroup>
                                </DrawingGroup>
                                <GeometryDrawing Brush="#FF3E79B4" Geometry="M19.2158,27.348L28.2357,18.3281 30.359,20.4514 21.3391,29.4713 19.2158,27.348z M29.6123,16.9515C29.9648,16.599,30.3236,16.599,30.6761,16.9515L31.7357,18.0111C32.0882,18.3636,32.0882,18.7224,31.7357,19.0749L30.8614,19.9492 28.7226,17.829 29.6123,16.9515z M16.7052,31.677L18.7228,27.8409 20.8461,29.9642 17.01,31.9818C16.949,32.0139,16.8742,32.0025,16.8254,31.9538L16.7331,31.8615C16.6845,31.8128,16.6732,31.738,16.7052,31.677z" />
                            </DrawingGroup>
                        </DrawingImage.Drawing>
                    </DrawingImage>
                </Image.Source>
            </Image>
```

I think this is the easiest solution.

Comment: Thank you. This is promising but very tedious. I was hoping there was an "easier" way to use Canvas directly or automatically convert it.

Comment: @Mensur, I Agree, you can't convert all canvas manually. Now I tried another approach. see above.

Comment: @Mensur, Where did you create this canvas Icon? Instead of creating cnavas, you may create DrawingBrush.

Comment: Blend option can work. How did you do the conversion if I may ask? I don't mid copy pasting but I just didn;t want to do it manually. Unfortunately the tool that creates the icons does not give options when creating XAML. It always gives Canvas.

Comment: In Blend, go to `Tools` -- `MakeBrush Resource`--`Make DrawingBrush Resource`.  if you are new to Blend, you may need to play around a bit.

Comment: I am not seeing that option in Blend for Visual Studio 2017. Do I need to have something special installed?

Comment: 1. Create a WPF project in Blend
2. copy your Canvas XAML code into MainWindow XAML
3. you can see the view of your icon in Desing view.
5. In Design View, press CTRL+A to select all **(Very important)**
6. now go to Tools -- MakeBrush Resource--Make DrawingBrush Resource
7. you can save into separate resource dictionary or in the same window resources.

Comment: I am still not seeing the option to make a Brush. Followed your instructions and tried several different variations of selection. [see image](http://medicfamily3.com/2018-08-20_22-29-00.jpg) Someone else seems to be referring to the same steps [here[(https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/b96a1f2c-aad4-4552-9732-75c41a71893b/how-to-convert-ui-element-into-drawing-brush?forum=wpf). Could this be an issue with the version of Blend? I am using latest 2017 version.

Comment: Your selection was wrong. I pointed in Design view, NOT in XAML view.  Click the area where you see the image and then press Ctrl+A

Comment: Else you can select the first `canvas` from your `Objects and Timeline` window. then go to `Tools`

Comment: YES, selecting the item on the timeline was the key! Thanks Suresh!

Answer (score 1):

I don't use Infragistics controls, but I believe they follow the standard WPF controls.

I used `image` control and try to display your canvas path image.

define the `Geometry` from your canvas path in resource

```
<Geometry x:Key="StopGeometry">M13,11.3814v18.115c0.0083,0.2845,0.2134,0.5036,0.4896,0.5036h4c0.2807,0,0.5104,-0.2297,0.5104,-0.5104v-18.088l7.6585,7.6695c0.1259,0.1261,0.3415,0.0369,0.3415,-0.1413v-6.2525c0,-0.2125,-0.0845,-0.4162,-0.2349,-0.5663l-9.934,-9.9139c-0.2999,-0.2654,-0.4015,-0.2654,-0.6944,0.0157L5.235,12.0908c-0.1504,0.1501,-0.235,0.3539,-0.235,0.5664v6.2414c0,0.1782,0.2154,0.2674,0.3414,0.1414L13,11.3814z</Geometry>
```

in XAML

```
<Image Height="100" Width="100">
            <Image.Source>
                <DrawingImage >
                    <DrawingImage.Drawing>
                        <GeometryDrawing Brush="#3E79B4"  Geometry="{StaticResource StopGeometry}"/>
                    </DrawingImage.Drawing>
                </DrawingImage>
            </Image.Source>
</Image>
```

Comment: This works OK and I have done something similar in cases of simple icons composed of a single `Path`. What about more complex case (please see updated question with more complex example)?

Comment: @Mensur Use a GeometryGroup for the GeometryDrawing's Geometry.

Comment: If you have several path data GeometryGroup will help. but in your case, you need to consider additional consideration on `RenderTransform`, `Polygon` representation.