# How to use a path data from a resource dictionary in UWP

Tags: xaml, win-universal-app

This is trivial thing but yet it does not work.

I have something like this (it is in its own folder)

```
<ResourceDictionary>
    <Path x:Key="Test"
          Stroke="Black"
          Fill="Gray" 
          Data="M 10,100 C 10,300 300,-200 300,100" />
</ResourceDictionary>
```

Now I want to use it

```
<Page>
    <Page.Resources>
        <ResourceDictionary>
            <ResourceDictionary.MergeDictionaries>
                <ResourceDictionary Source="MyFolder/MyResourceDictionary.xaml/>
            </ResourceDictionary.MergeDictionaries>
        </ResourceDictionary>
    </Page.Resources>
    <ContentPresenter Content="{StaticResource Test}"/>
<Page/>
```

This will throw an exception, but I don't understand why. Exactly the same scenario in wpf works fine.

Comment: If you change ContentPresenter to `<Path Style="{StaticResource Test}"/>` How about then? Sorry don't have time to tinker today, but you could always just do something like [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13292179/best-way-to-use-a-vector-image-in-wpf/13293017#13293017).

Comment: @ChrisW. Same happens, but the accepted answer works:) thank you.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

What about this solution?

Declare your `GeometryData`

```
<x:String x:Key="TestPathGeomerty">M 10,100 C 10,300 300,-200 300,100</x:String>
```

And use `Path`, instead `ContentPresenter`

```
<Path Data="{StaticResource TestPathGeomerty}"
      Fill="Red"/>
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I'll check whether it works.

Comment: I checked it before publish. It is 100% working solution.

Comment: Is there a solution for an actual Path as a StaticResource? I would like to have other Path properties contained within the resource, not just the Data.

Comment: I'm getting a XAML intellisense error "The resource "TestPathGeomerty" has an incompatible type". I'm targeting the Fall Creators Update.

Comment: @Magnus See my answer for a solution that contains the actual control in the resource.

Comment: I'm not able to compile this in the latest version of VS 2017 (April 2018 update). That's why I added another answer.

Answer (score 5):

The Path.Data property is of type `Geometry` so define it as a `Geometry` instead of a `string`

```
<Geometry x:Key="TestPathGeomerty">M 10,100 C 10,300 300,-200 300,100</Geometry>

<Path Data="{StaticResource TestPathGeomerty}"
      Fill="Red"/>
```

Answer (score 4):

In WPF, you can share the same instance within multiple controls. Unfortunately this is not possible in UWP.

The only solution that is guaranteed to work in UWP, is to define a DataTemplate in your resource containing the icon.

It is also better to use PathIcon instead of Path. PathIcon makes use of the Foreground property that will be inherited from your parent controls.

Here's an example on how to share Data paths for icons that will automatically scale (by using a Viewbox).

```
<Page.Resources>
    <DataTemplate x:Key="MagnifyingGlassPathIconCT">
        <Viewbox Stretch="Uniform">
            <PathIcon Data="M44,12 C32,12 22,22 22,34 22,46 32,56 44,56 56,56 66,46 66,34 66,22 56,12 44,12z M44,0 C63,0 78,15 78,34 78,53 63,68 44,68 40,68 36.5,67.5 33,66 L32.5,66 14,90 0,79.5 18,55.5 17,55 C13,49 10,42 10,34 10,15 25,0 44,0z" />
        </Viewbox>
    </DataTemplate>
</Page.Resources>

<StackPanel Padding="40" HorizontalAlignment="Left">
    <!--  Plain icon  -->
    <ContentPresenter
        Width="40"
        Height="40"
        ContentTemplate="{StaticResource MagnifyingGlassPathIconCT}"
        Foreground="Purple" />
    <!--  Icon with a border  -->
    <Border
        Width="40" Padding="7"
        Height="40"
        BorderBrush="Black"
        BorderThickness="2">
        <ContentPresenter ContentTemplate="{StaticResource MagnifyingGlassPathIconCT}" Foreground="Red" />
    </Border>
    <!--  Icon in a normal Button  -->
    <Button
        Width="40"
        Height="40"
        ContentTemplate="{StaticResource MagnifyingGlassPathIconCT}"
        Foreground="RoyalBlue" />
    <!--  Icon in an AppBarButton  -->
    <AppBarButton
        Width="40"
        ContentTemplate="{StaticResource MagnifyingGlassPathIconCT}"
        Foreground="Black"
        Label="Search" />
</StackPanel>
```

[image: This is the result]

Comment: This answer is amazing. No hacks, and uses a ContentPresenter to change the stroke color, and resources for the data.

Answer (score 3):

For a solution that lets you define it in a Style, try writting an attached property like this:

```
    public static string GetPathData(DependencyObject obj)
    {
        return (string)obj.GetValue(PathDataProperty);
    }

    public static void SetPathData(DependencyObject obj, string value)
    {
        obj.SetValue(PathDataProperty, value);
    }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty PathDataProperty =
        DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached("PathData", typeof(string), typeof(ElementExtensions), new PropertyMetadata(null, (d, e) =>
        {
            if (d is Path path)
            {
                Binding b = new Binding { Source = e.NewValue };
                path.SetBinding(Path.DataProperty, b);
            }
        }));
```

And now you can define a style like so:

```
<Style x:Key="BasePathStyle" TargetType="Path">
    <Setter Property="e:ElementExtensions.PathData" Value="M 10,100 C 10,300 300,-200 300,100" />
</Style>
```

And then use it like so:

```
<Path Style="{StaticResource BasePathStyle}" />
```