# Is there any clean way to use vector images via pack url in WPF/Xaml

Tags: .net, wpf, xaml, vector-graphics

I figured out how to get a xaml from an svg file (.svg->Inkscape->pdf->ai->ExpressionDesign->xaml).

The conversion either gives me a resource dictionary with a DrawingBrush or a Xaml File with a canvas.

Now i'm searching for a clean way to use the vector image via a pack url so i can use it in a clean way from my ViewModel. This is the xaml fragment that works nicely with an ImagePath(string) containing the pack URL to a (resource) .png file. Is there anything alike for vector images?

```
// View Model: 
MainMenuEntry.ImagePath = "pack://application:,,,/MyBeautifulApp.Wpf.MainGui;component/CommonResources/OpenFile16x16.png"

// .Xaml File
<DataTemplate>
    <Button Command ="{Binding ClickCommand}" Margin="3,0,0,0">
        <Button.Template>
            <ControlTemplate>
                <Image Source="{Binding ImagePath}" Width="16" Height="16"  Stretch="Uniform" VerticalAlignment="Center" />
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Button.Template>
    </Button>
</DataTemplate>
```

Only way i found it to work at all was with a Binding of ImageSource to a StaticResource with the DrawingBrush (in ResourceDictionary) but that doesn't help me with a view model where i might have either a bitmap file or a vector image. There must be any sane way to handle vector images like with svg in html?

Comment: Not sure what you mean by "clean" way. The way I do it is AI -> [XAML Conversion](http://www.mikeswanson.com/xamlexport/) -> Resource. If it's a single Path then I just make it a Style template. If it's multiple I use a [different template](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13292179/best-way-to-use-a-vector-image-in-wpf/13293017#13293017) method. Then it all sits in a resource dictionary and is called via StaticResource, whether from XAML or codebehind, works like a charm.

Comment: With clean i meant straightforward like pseudocode "pack://application:,,,/MyBeautifulApp.Wpf.MainGui;component/CommonResources/OpenFileVectorGraphic.xaml" that i could bind just like the png. Guess i'll now make a MenuItemCommand class for the viewmodel with either multiple properties for bitmap/vector icon or with an object property and a style/template that dynamically builds appropriate items depending of the type returned by the property (packpath string/xaml graph).

Comment: Ah, well if you really want to use Image.Source you could port your XAML Vector into a DrawingImage resource and still be able to do `<Image Source="{StaticResource DrawingImage]" ... />`

Answer (score 0):

For organizational purposes create a separate class library project for your assets.  Define your XAML vector graphic in a ResourceDictionary

Assets/Category/my-asset.xaml:

```
<ResourceDictionary 
  xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
  xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
  xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
  xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
  mc:Ignorable="d">
<VisualBrush x:Key="my-asset" Stretch="Uniform">
    <VisualBrush.Visual>
        <Canvas Width="48.822" Height="53.243">
                 <Path {...} />
            </Canvas>
        </VisualBrush.Visual>
    </VisualBrush>
</ResourceDictionary>
```

Define a ResourceDictionary that contains a reference to all of your assets:

Assets/Assets.xaml

```
<ResourceDictionary 
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" >
    <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
        <ResourceDictionary Source="Category/my-asset.xaml" />
        {...}
    </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
</ResourceDictionary>
```

In your App.xaml load the Assets.xaml

```
<Application x:Class="MyApp.App"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             StartupUri="MainWindow.xaml">
    <Application.Resources>
        <ResourceDictionary>
            <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
                <ResourceDictionary Source="pack://application:,,,/ClientAssets;component/Assets/Assets.xaml" />
        </ResourceDictionary>
    </Application.Resources>
</Application>
```

With this in place you may use your graphics where ever you like as a brush in a rectangle.

```
<Rectangle Grid.Row="2" Fill="{StaticResource my-asset}" Height="16" Width="16" />
```