# xaml vector image in WPF: 'TextBox' TargetType does not match type of element 'ContentControl'

Tags: wpf, xaml, vector

As the title says, I'm trying to use a .xaml vector image in WPF but instead of the image, I get prompted this message.

the code I'm using was provided by [Chris W.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13292179/best-way-to-use-a-vector-image-in-wpf/13293017#13293017)

```
<!-- Plop this in your resource dictionary or your resource declaration -->
<Style x:Key="TheAwesomeXAMLimage" TargetType="ContentControl">
        <!-- Add additional Setters Here -->
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="ContentControl">

                            <!-- Just Paste your XAML here -->

            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>                      
</Style>
```

(obviously I pasted the vector XAML in my project)

and I'm calling it with

```
    <ContentControl Style="{StaticResource TheAwesomeXAMLimage}"/>
```

I'm absolutely clueless, sorry

this is the .xaml with the vector image inside:

```
<Window
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:aditum_desktop_admin"
    xmlns:Themes="clr-namespace:Microsoft.Windows.Themes;assembly=PresentationFramework.Aero" x:Name="Home" x:Class="aditum_desktop_admin.Main"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    Title="aditumAdmin V0.01" Height="300" Width="300" Foreground="#BF7300" Background="Black">
<Window.Resources>
    <LinearGradientBrush x:Key="TextBoxBorder" EndPoint="0,20" MappingMode="Absolute" StartPoint="0,0">
        <GradientStop Color="#ABADB3" Offset="0.05"/>
        <GradientStop Color="#E2E3EA" Offset="0.07"/>
        <GradientStop Color="#E3E9EF" Offset="1"/>
    </LinearGradientBrush>
    <Style x:Key="VortechLogo" BasedOn="{x:Null}" TargetType="{x:Type TextBox}">
        <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.ControlTextBrushKey}}"/>
        <Setter Property="Background" Value="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.WindowBrushKey}}"/>
        <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="{StaticResource TextBoxBorder}"/>
        <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="1"/>
        <Setter Property="Padding" Value="1"/>
        <Setter Property="AllowDrop" Value="true"/>
        <Setter Property="FocusVisualStyle" Value="{x:Null}"/>
        <Setter Property="ScrollViewer.PanningMode" Value="VerticalFirst"/>
        <Setter Property="Stylus.IsFlicksEnabled" Value="False"/>
        <Style.Triggers>
            <MultiTrigger>
                <MultiTrigger.Conditions>
                    <Condition Property="IsInactiveSelectionHighlightEnabled" Value="true"/>
                    <Condition Property="IsSelectionActive" Value="false"/>
                </MultiTrigger.Conditions>
                <Setter Property="SelectionBrush" Value="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.InactiveSelectionHighlightBrushKey}}"/>
            </MultiTrigger>
        </Style.Triggers>
    </Style>
</Window.Resources>
<Grid Background="#FF585858">
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition/>
        <RowDefinition/>
        <RowDefinition/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="146"/>
        <ColumnDefinition/>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <Button x:Name="buttonAddClient" Content="addClient" Background="#FF1E1E1E" Foreground="#FFBF7300" Grid.Row="0" Click="buttonAddClient_Click" BorderThickness="0" Style="{StaticResource {x:Static ToolBar.ButtonStyleKey}}" Margin="10,26.52,10,27.52" Width="126" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" Height="35"/>
    <Button x:Name="buttonAddUser" Content="addUser" Margin="10,26.02,10,28.02" Background="#FF1E1E1E" BorderBrush="#FF585858"  Foreground="#FFBF7300" Grid.Row="1" Click="buttonAddUser_Click" BorderThickness="0" Style="{StaticResource {x:Static ToolBar.ButtonStyleKey}}" Width="126" Height="35"/>
    <Button x:Name="buttonAddScanlocation" Content="addScanlocation" Margin="10,22.02,10,31.353" Background="#FF1E1E1E" Foreground="#FFBF7300" Grid.Row="2" Click="buttonAddScanLocation_Click" BorderThickness="0" Style="{StaticResource {x:Static ToolBar.ButtonStyleKey}}" Width="126" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" Height="35" />
    <Button x:Name="buttonEditClient" Content="editClient" Background="#FF1E1E1E" Foreground="#FFBF7300" Grid.Row="0" Click="buttonEditClient_Click" BorderThickness="0" Style="{StaticResource {x:Static ToolBar.ButtonStyleKey}}" Margin="10,27,10,28" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" Height="35" Grid.Column="1" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"/>
    <Button x:Name="buttonEditUser" Content="editUser" Margin="10,26.5,10,28.5" Background="#FF1E1E1E" BorderBrush="#FF585858"  Foreground="#FFBF7300" Grid.Row="1" Click="buttonEditUser_Click" BorderThickness="0" Style="{StaticResource {x:Static ToolBar.ButtonStyleKey}}" Height="35" Grid.Column="1" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"/>
    <Button x:Name="buttonEditScanlocation" Content="editScanlocation" Margin="10,22.833,10,32.166" Background="#FF1E1E1E" Foreground="#FFBF7300" Grid.Row="2" Click="buttonEditScanLocation_Click" BorderThickness="0" Style="{StaticResource {x:Static ToolBar.ButtonStyleKey}}" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" Height="35" Grid.Column="1" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" d:LayoutOverrides="TopMargin, BottomMargin" />
    <ContentControl Style="{StaticResource svgLogo}"/>
</Grid>
```

and this is the logo itself:

```
<Style x:Key="svgLogo" TargetType="ContentControl">
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="ContentControl">

                    <Canvas xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation" Name="svg3694" Width="650" Height="230" Canvas.Left="0" Canvas.Top="0">
                        <Canvas.RenderTransform>
                            <TranslateTransform X="0" Y="0"/>
                        </Canvas.RenderTransform>
                        <Canvas.Resources>
                            <Canvas xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml" Name="Layer0_0_FILL" x:Key="Layer0_0_FILL">
                                <Path Name="path3680" Fill="#FFFFFFFF" Data=" M 571.6 65.4 L 567.6 65.4 Q 563.3 65.4 563.3 69.75 L 563.3 152.9 Q 563.3 157.2 567.6 157.2 L 571.6 157.2 Q 575.8 157.2 575.8 152.9 L 575.8 125.95 Q 575.8 120.75 577.45 116.2 579.1 111.75 582.1 108.4 585.1 105.1 589 103.3 593.15 101.4 597.75 101.4 601.6 101.4 604.2 102.75 606.55 103.9 608 106.25 609.25 108.3 609.75 111.5 L 610.3 117.95 610.3 152.9 Q 610.3 157.2 614.55 157.2 L 618.6 157.2 Q 622.85 157.2 622.85 152.9 L 622.85 115.05 Q 622.85 108.75 621.5 104.05 620.1 99.3 617.4 96.2 614.6 93.05 610.35 91.45 606 89.85 600.25 89.85 595.55 89.85 591.3 91.3 587.45 92.65 584.1 95 581.15 97.15 578.85 99.9 576.8 102.35 575.7 104.95 L 575.45 104.95 Q 575.8 102.6 575.8 99.5 L 575.8 69.75 Q 575.8 65.4 571.6 65.4 M 552.75 96.9 Q 542.05 89.85 531.05 89.85 521.1 90.8 516.85 92.5 510.5 95.05 505.75 99.75 501.05 104.45 498.55 110.65 495.9 117.1 495.9 124.3 495.9 131.6 498.45 138.05 501 144.3 505.7 148.95 510.45 153.65 516.8 156.2 521.05 157.85 531.05 158.8 542.85 158.8 554.4 150.75 557.6 148.5 555.6 144.95 L 554.5 143.05 Q 552.3 139.5 548.65 141.85 539.85 147.85 531.9 147.85 526.95 147.85 522.6 146.05 518.4 144.25 515.3 141 512.15 137.85 510.5 133.5 508.8 129.15 508.8 124.2 508.8 119.2 510.45 114.8 512.15 110.6 515.2 107.45 518.35 104.25 522.5 102.55 526.75 100.75 531.65 100.75 538.6 100.75 546.3 105.7 550.05 107.9 552.25 104.7 L 553.5 102.75 Q 556.1 99.05 552.75 96.9 M 490.4 121.2 Q 490.4 114.3 488.55 108.6 486.65 102.8 483.1 98.65 479.4 94.4 474.2 92.2 468.8 89.85 462.1 89.85 455.1 89.85 449.05 92.35 443.05 94.75 438.6 99.25 434.1 103.8 431.7 110.1 429.2 116.65 429.2 124.3 429.2 131.55 431.75 137.9 434.2 144.2 438.85 148.8 443.55 153.6 449.9 156.1 454.1 157.85 464.05 158.8 474.6 158.8 486.25 151.75 489.7 149.7 487.55 146.05 L 486.4 144.05 Q 484.35 140.65 480.55 142.65 472 147.85 464.8 147.85 460.35 147.85 456.45 146.4 452.45 144.9 449.3 142.1 446.15 139.15 444.3 135.1 442.35 130.85 442.1 125.6 L 486 125.6 Q 490.4 125.6 490.4 121.2 M 467.9 100.85 Q 470.8 102 472.95 104.2 475.15 106.4 476.35 109.65 477.7 113.1 477.8 117.25 L 442.6 117.25 Q 443.25 113.2 445 109.9 446.7 106.65 449.25 104.4 451.8 102.1 455.05 100.95 458.2 99.75 461.85 99.75 465.15 99.75 467.9 100.85 M 409.6 77.65 Q 409.6 73.35 405.35 73.35 L 401.55 73.35 Q 397.3 73.35 397.3 77.65 L 397.3 92.05 392.6 92.05 Q 388.3 92.05 388.3 96.4 L 388.3 98.05 Q 388.3 102.35 392.5 102.35 L 397.05 102.35 397.05 133.5 Q 397.05 139.55 399 144.3 400.85 148.75 404.35 151.85 407.65 154.8 412.15 156.3 416.45 157.7 421.5 157.7 424.1 157.7 425.35 156.7 426.65 155.7 426.65 153.45 L 426.65 150.75 Q 426.65 148.45 425.7 147.55 424.65 146.6 422.1 146.4 417.05 146.05 414.05 143.55 412.05 141.85 410.9 139.1 409.6 136 409.6 131.6 L 409.6 102.35 421.15 102.35 Q 425.35 102.35 425.35 98.05 L 425.35 96.4 Q 425.35 92.05 421.05 92.05 L 409.6 92.05 409.6 77.65 M 359.25 92.2 Q 357 92.2 357 94.4 L 357 155 Q 357 157.2 359.25 157.2 L 360.25 157.2 Q 362.5 157.2 362.5 155 L 362.5 129.15 Q 362.5 123.55 363.8 118.1 365.15 112.3 367.75 107.9 370.55 103 374.4 100.35 378.75 97.4 383.95 97.4 386.8 97.4 386.8 95.2 L 386.8 94.05 Q 386.8 91.8 384.05 91.8 380.05 91.8 376.5 93.2 373.15 94.55 370.3 97.1 367.55 99.5 365.45 102.85 363.5 106.05 362.2 109.9 L 361.95 109.9 Q 362.5 107.55 362.5 104.6 L 362.5 94.4 Q 362.5 92.2 360.25 92.2 L 359.25 92.2 M 340.35 111.05 Q 337.8 104.95 333.15 100.4 328.5 95.75 322.45 93.2 316.2 90.6 309.35 90.6 302.5 90.6 296.2 93.2 290.2 95.75 285.55 100.4 280.85 104.95 278.3 111.05 275.65 117.35 275.65 124.3 275.65 131.45 278.3 137.85 280.85 144.05 285.55 148.8 290.2 153.5 296.2 156.1 302.5 158.8 309.35 158.8 316.2 158.8 322.45 156.1 328.45 153.5 333.15 148.8 337.8 144.05 340.35 137.85 343 131.45 343 124.3 343 117.35 340.35 111.05 M 329.1 104.05 Q 332.95 108 335.05 113.1 337.3 118.35 337.3 124.3 337.3 130.4 335.05 135.8 332.95 141.1 329.1 145.1 325.3 149 320.2 151.25 315.05 153.45 309.35 153.45 303.65 153.45 298.45 151.25 293.4 149 289.55 145.1 285.65 141.1 283.6 135.8 281.35 130.4 281.35 124.3 281.35 118.35 283.6 113.1 285.65 108 289.55 104.05 293.4 100.25 298.45 98.1 303.65 95.95 309.35 95.95 315.05 95.95 320.2 98.1 325.3 100.25 329.1 104.05 M 276.7 66.15 Q 274.75 66.15 274.25 68 L 247.35 139.8 Q 245.75 144.05 243.8 150.75 L 243.55 150.75 Q 241.65 144.05 240.05 139.8 L 213.25 68 Q 212.7 66.15 210.8 66.15 L 209.4 66.15 Q 206.65 66.15 207.55 68.8 L 240.05 155.35 Q 240.6 157.2 242.55 157.2 L 245 157.2 Q 246.9 157.2 247.5 155.35 L 280 68.8 Q 280.8 66.15 278.15 66.15 L 276.7 66.15 Z"/>
                            </Canvas>
                            <Canvas xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml" Name="Layer0_0_STROKES_1_FILL" x:Key="Layer0_0_STROKES_1_FILL">
                                <Path Name="path3683" Fill="#FFFFFFFF" Data=" M 163.2 117.9 L 162.85 118.2 138.75 143.5 Q 135.5 146.45 132 148.6 128.2 150.95 123.8 152.6 120.9 153.55 119.1 153.95 116.7 154.55 114.1 154.85 L 106.45 155.3 106.15 155.25 103.4 155.15 97.95 154.4 Q 95.6 153.95 92.55 153 89.55 152 87.25 150.85 84.65 149.6 82.15 148 79.85 146.45 77.35 144.45 L 75.05 142.4 74.9 142.3 74.85 142.2 74.8 142.2 73 140.4 72.9 140.25 68.9 135.6 Q 67.2 133.35 65.5 130.45 62.45 125 60.95 119 L 60.6 117.45 59.6 110.45 59.6 109.65 59.55 109.25 59.55 103.3 59.6 102.95 59.6 102.55 59.9 99.4 59.95 99.2 59.95 99 60.05 98.65 60.3 97.1 Q 60.3 97.05 60.45 96.3 L 61.15 93.25 64.05 85.3 67.7 78.95 67.95 78.65 68.8 77.4 Q 70.8 74.75 72.7 72.65 L 76.45 68.95 77.05 68.45 Q 79.15 66.65 81.7 64.8 L 83.5 63.6 83.85 63.45 84.75 62.85 91.15 59.75 91.45 59.6 91.8 59.5 Q 96.9 57.55 102.35 56.75 105.25 56.35 107.55 56.2 L 112.65 56.15 Q 117.45 56.35 122.05 57.3 124.9 57.95 126.35 58.45 128.1 58.95 130.3 59.85 L 135.1 62.15 135.5 62.4 Q 135.7 62.5 137.05 63.3 139.65 64.85 142.4 66.95 L 146.35 70.4 Q 148.05 71.95 149.1 73.15 149.3 73.35 150.7 74.95 L 151.1 75.45 151.25 75.6 Q 151.35 75.7 151.4 75.6 151.5 75.55 151.4 75.45 L 151.3 75.3 150.9 74.8 Q 149.6 73.15 149.4 72.9 L 142.95 66.3 Q 140.15 63.85 137.75 62.25 L 134.55 60.25 Q 132.55 59.1 130.95 58.35 129.5 57.65 126.95 56.65 124.3 55.7 122.6 55.25 117.9 53.95 112.8 53.5 L 108.15 53.3 107.85 53.25 107.5 53.25 Q 105.1 53.25 101.95 53.5 96.05 54.05 90.5 55.85 L 90.15 55.95 80.6 60.2 79.25 61.05 Q 76.9 62.45 73.95 64.7 L 72.05 66.25 71.75 66.55 71.4 66.8 69 69.05 Q 66.5 71.45 64.45 73.95 L 63.15 75.65 62.85 75.95 58.65 82.5 57.85 84.05 Q 57.25 85.3 57.1 85.65 L 56.35 87.25 53.3 97 52.1 106.35 52.1 107.2 52.05 107.6 52.2 114.4 53.95 124.7 55.65 129.95 56.2 131.25 Q 57 133.2 57.7 134.6 59.3 137.75 61.4 140.9 L 63.5 143.9 64.65 145.3 Q 65 145.8 65.8 146.7 L 65.95 146.85 66.7 147.75 66.85 147.9 67 148.1 70.75 151.85 Q 73.5 154.45 76.3 156.45 79.15 158.55 82.35 160.3 85.35 162 88.75 163.3 91.8 164.55 95.4 165.45 L 97.95 166.05 105.9 167.15 106.3 167.15 Q 106.6 167.2 107.2 167.2 L 107.6 167.25 108.95 167.3 Q 109 167.3 109.1 167.3 L 112.05 167.3 Q 112.6 167.3 112.85 167.25 L 114.9 167.2 115.3 167.15 Q 118.7 166.9 121.65 166.35 124.7 165.85 127.75 164.9 133.5 163.25 138.8 160.3 143.45 157.75 147.9 154.15 L 149.85 152.5 150.05 152.3 150.15 152.25 174.2 129.55 Q 176.6 127.25 176.7 123.95 176.8 120.65 174.5 118.2 172.2 115.8 168.9 115.7 165.6 115.6 163.2 117.9 M 163.35 84.75 L 162.85 85.2 126.25 124.9 126.05 125.05 126 125.15 124.15 126.9 Q 123.1 127.85 121.4 128.9 118.5 130.7 114.9 131.6 L 111.25 132.2 109.8 132.25 109.55 132.3 107.9 132.3 107.65 132.25 107.4 132.25 Q 103.45 132.1 100 130.7 96.45 129.4 93.3 126.75 L 92.5 126.1 92.15 125.75 92.05 125.7 90.35 124 87.9 120.85 Q 85.65 117.45 84.7 113.65 84.15 111.7 83.95 109.7 L 83.85 107.9 83.8 107.85 83.8 105.65 Q 83.95 101.55 85.2 97.95 86.5 94.25 88.75 91.15 L 90.75 88.7 90.85 88.6 90.85 88.55 91.3 88.1 91.4 88.05 91.55 87.85 93.6 85.95 93.95 85.7 Q 96.5 83.55 100.05 81.95 L 100.45 81.8 100.65 81.7 100.85 81.65 101.7 81.35 101.9 81.25 102.1 81.2 103.3 80.8 Q 105.1 80.3 106.55 80.1 L 109.8 79.8 Q 111.2 79.65 112.9 79.75 115.8 79.9 118.55 80.6 L 123.35 82.35 Q 123.6 82.45 125.35 83.4 L 127.1 84.5 Q 128.05 85.15 129.9 86.65 L 132.9 89.65 133.15 90 133.25 90.1 Q 133.35 90.2 133.4 90.1 133.5 90.05 133.4 89.95 L 133.3 89.85 133.05 89.5 130.3 86.25 Q 128.9 84.85 127.6 83.8 127.45 83.65 125.9 82.5 L 121.6 80.05 119.05 79 Q 115.95 78 113.1 77.65 111.25 77.4 109.75 77.4 107.85 77.3 106.25 77.45 104.3 77.6 102.6 77.95 L 100.75 78.35 99.85 78.65 99.6 78.7 98.9 78.95 Q 95.2 80.15 91.65 82.55 L 91.2 82.85 89.1 84.5 89 84.55 88.7 84.85 88.5 85 87.9 85.6 87.8 85.65 85.05 88.5 84.9 88.75 81.95 92.9 80.35 96 80.25 96.3 80.1 96.55 78.8 100.5 Q 78.2 102.8 77.9 105.25 L 77.75 107.75 77.7 107.9 77.7 110.1 Q 77.8 112.75 78.2 115.05 78.5 116.8 78.75 117.5 79.05 118.7 79.5 119.95 L 80.45 122.35 Q 81.25 124.1 81.6 124.65 82.25 125.9 82.95 126.85 83.45 127.65 84.45 128.95 L 84.85 129.45 Q 84.95 129.65 85.25 129.95 L 85.35 130.1 86.45 131.3 86.5 131.4 89.8 134.5 90.05 134.7 90.15 134.8 90.3 134.9 90.8 135.35 92.4 136.5 92.7 136.65 92.95 136.85 96.4 138.8 Q 98.95 140 101.35 140.7 103.05 141.2 103.9 141.35 L 106.5 141.8 106.65 141.8 106.8 141.85 107.15 141.85 107.8 141.95 108.1 141.95 108.25 142 109.7 142.05 110 142.1 114.25 142 Q 115.55 141.95 116.8 141.7 117.65 141.6 119.35 141.2 121.05 140.8 121.9 140.5 123.3 140.05 124.35 139.6 125.35 139.25 126.7 138.55 129.1 137.25 131.05 135.9 L 132.55 134.75 132.8 134.6 133.05 134.35 133.55 133.95 174.2 96.55 Q 176.65 94.3 176.75 90.95 176.9 87.65 174.65 85.2 172.4 82.75 169.1 82.65 165.8 82.5 163.35 84.75 M 162 53.35 L 162.3 53.6 167.75 59.35 168.25 60 168.45 60.2 Q 168.55 60.3 168.6 60.2 168.7 60.15 168.6 60.05 L 168.45 59.85 162.4 52.9 Q 160.05 50.45 157.35 48.1 L 155.6 46.65 155.4 46.45 152.85 44.45 152.6 44.3 152.4 44.1 144.1 38.75 138.2 35.85 138.05 35.75 137.85 35.7 136.5 35.15 Q 133.9 34.05 130.85 33.05 L 119.85 30.45 114.75 29.8 114.3 29.8 114.1 29.75 113.85 29.75 113 29.65 Q 112.4 29.65 112.1 29.6 111.5 29.6 111.25 29.55 110.65 29.55 110.35 29.5 L 109.45 29.5 Q 109.15 29.45 108.55 29.45 L 107.65 29.45 Q 107.05 29.45 106.75 29.4 L 104 29.45 Q 96.2 29.6 88.9 31.25 85.15 32.05 81.15 33.35 77.25 34.65 73.55 36.35 65.8 39.95 59.05 45.15 L 58.15 45.8 52.35 50.75 46.95 56.3 41 63.8 40.7 64.25 Q 38 68.15 35.95 72.05 33.7 76.25 32.1 80.45 L 30.65 84.6 28.55 92.8 27 105.55 26.95 107.85 26.9 107.95 27.1 116.05 27.15 116.35 27.7 121.9 27.75 122.2 27.8 122.35 27.8 122.5 28.5 126.55 Q 29.4 131.25 30.9 135.65 L 32.95 141.2 33.05 141.3 38.9 152.55 Q 41.2 156.25 44.25 160.1 L 50.3 166.9 Q 53.45 170.15 56.85 173 60.35 175.9 64 178.35 67.75 180.9 71.55 182.85 75.95 185.05 79.4 186.35 83.35 187.9 87.45 188.95 94.8 190.95 103.35 191.6 L 105.8 191.7 106.05 191.75 107.15 191.75 107.6 191.8 110.95 191.8 Q 115.3 191.7 118.35 191.4 125.4 190.75 132.1 188.95 134.6 188.3 138.35 187 141.1 186 144.05 184.7 L 144.4 184.5 144.55 184.45 151.05 181.1 151.35 180.9 151.65 180.75 152.8 180.05 153.1 179.9 153.2 179.8 161.4 174.05 161.6 173.85 165.85 170.25 165.95 170.2 174.2 162.3 Q 176.55 159.95 176.65 156.65 176.7 153.35 174.4 150.95 172.1 148.6 168.8 148.5 165.5 148.45 163.1 150.75 L 162.85 150.95 155.4 158.75 155.35 158.85 151.65 162.25 151.5 162.35 145.25 167.15 145.1 167.25 145 167.3 144.8 167.45 143.85 168.05 Q 143.8 168.15 143.65 168.2 L 138.9 171 138.35 171.25 138.25 171.35 138.1 171.4 137.8 171.55 Q 136.2 172.4 133.2 173.65 130.7 174.65 128.2 175.45 122.45 177.25 116.8 178 113.5 178.4 110.55 178.55 L 109.75 178.6 Q 109.2 178.6 108.95 178.65 L 106.4 178.65 106.2 178.7 106.1 178.7 106 178.65 104 178.65 Q 96.8 178.4 90.4 177 83.35 175.45 76.75 172.35 73.15 170.65 70.1 168.8 67 166.9 63.75 164.45 60.55 161.95 57.75 159.3 L 57.4 158.95 57.3 158.9 52.2 153.5 Q 49.7 150.7 47.2 147.1 L 43.2 140.6 43 140.1 41.65 137.5 41.6 137.35 39.6 132.6 Q 38.15 128.9 37.15 124.65 L 37.05 124.4 36.35 121.05 36.35 120.95 36.3 120.8 35.55 115.85 35 106.8 35.2 100.45 36.1 93.05 37.55 86.6 37.6 86.5 37.6 86.35 38.55 83.35 38.6 83.1 38.7 82.85 Q 40.05 78.8 41.85 75.05 43.65 71.25 45.9 67.7 L 51.4 60.15 Q 51.6 59.85 51.75 59.75 L 56.6 54.35 62.25 49.2 Q 65.4 46.65 68.7 44.4 72.15 42.1 75.5 40.45 79.05 38.65 82.55 37.3 86.6 35.8 89.8 35 96.85 33.15 104.15 32.7 105.35 32.6 105.9 32.6 L 106.15 32.6 106.35 32.55 112 32.5 Q 112.25 32.55 112.85 32.55 113.4 32.55 113.7 32.6 L 113.9 32.6 123.05 33.55 123.25 33.6 123.45 33.6 130.25 35.1 Q 133.05 35.9 135.85 36.9 L 137.15 37.4 137.5 37.5 142.8 39.85 150.8 44.4 156.8 48.8 Q 159.65 51.1 162 53.35 Z"/>
                            </Canvas>
                        </Canvas.Resources>
                        <Canvas Name="g3692">
                            <Canvas.RenderTransform>
                                <MatrixTransform Matrix="1 0 0 1 0 0"/>
                            </Canvas.RenderTransform>
                        </Canvas>
                    </Canvas>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
```

Comment: You'll have to show me how you're using it, or at least a minimal example to reproduce it. Since there would have to be something implicit for `TextBox` to even be included in the error you're receiving I can only assume there's something more going on here, but we can get you sorted one way or another. There's also several other methods of using xaml vector depending on the need. :)

Comment: gladly. I ctrl+F'd "TextBox" where I pasted the <Style x:key[...]> (I put it in App.xaml because I noticed this is where saved styles are saved to) with no result. when I pasted the <ContentControl> into the page where I wanted to add the xaml vector image, it instantly gave me the error. I checked whether or not I mistakenly pasted it into a textbox but I don't even have textboxes on this window.

please let me know of any info you might need :)

Comment: update: trying it on new pages doesn't result in the same error for some reason but it doesn't show the logo. it's just invisible. opacity is 100%, visibility: visible

Comment: Ya again man, it would be much easier if we could see your code. :)

Comment: done, I added it to the initial question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, so there's several things I'd change in there but for the moment let's try to remedy your error (Which wouldn't be connected) and get your logo displaying.

For starters let's get your logo working. Notice that when I strip off the stuff whatever tool you're using to export the Path data adds, it works just fine like this.

```
<Style x:Key="svgLogo" TargetType="ContentControl">
   <Setter Property="Template">
      <Setter.Value>
         <ControlTemplate TargetType="ContentControl">

            <!-- I just used the same dimensions you had set already -->
            <Canvas Width="650" Height="230">
               <Path Fill="#FFFF0000" Data="M 163.2 117.9 L 162.85 118.2 138.75 143.5 Q 135.5 146.45 132 148.6 128.2 150.95 123.8 152.6 120.9 153.55 119.1 153.95 116.7 154.55 114.1 154.85 L 106.45 155.3 106.15 155.25 103.4 155.15 97.95 154.4 Q 95.6 153.95 92.55 153 89.55 152 87.25 150.85 84.65 149.6 82.15 148 79.85 146.45 77.35 144.45 L 75.05 142.4 74.9 142.3 74.85 142.2 74.8 142.2 73 140.4 72.9 140.25 68.9 135.6 Q 67.2 133.35 65.5 130.45 62.45 125 60.95 119 L 60.6 117.45 59.6 110.45 59.6 109.65 59.55 109.25 59.55 103.3 59.6 102.95 59.6 102.55 59.9 99.4 59.95 99.2 59.95 99 60.05 98.65 60.3 97.1 Q 60.3 97.05 60.45 96.3 L 61.15 93.25 64.05 85.3 67.7 78.95 67.95 78.65 68.8 77.4 Q 70.8 74.75 72.7 72.65 L 76.45 68.95 77.05 68.45 Q 79.15 66.65 81.7 64.8 L 83.5 63.6 83.85 63.45 84.75 62.85 91.15 59.75 91.45 59.6 91.8 59.5 Q 96.9 57.55 102.35 56.75 105.25 56.35 107.55 56.2 L 112.65 56.15 Q 117.45 56.35 122.05 57.3 124.9 57.95 126.35 58.45 128.1 58.95 130.3 59.85 L 135.1 62.15 135.5 62.4 Q 135.7 62.5 137.05 63.3 139.65 64.85 142.4 66.95 L 146.35 70.4 Q 148.05 71.95 149.1 73.15 149.3 73.35 150.7 74.95 L 151.1 75.45 151.25 75.6 Q 151.35 75.7 151.4 75.6 151.5 75.55 151.4 75.45 L 151.3 75.3 150.9 74.8 Q 149.6 73.15 149.4 72.9 L 142.95 66.3 Q 140.15 63.85 137.75 62.25 L 134.55 60.25 Q 132.55 59.1 130.95 58.35 129.5 57.65 126.95 56.65 124.3 55.7 122.6 55.25 117.9 53.95 112.8 53.5 L 108.15 53.3 107.85 53.25 107.5 53.25 Q 105.1 53.25 101.95 53.5 96.05 54.05 90.5 55.85 L 90.15 55.95 80.6 60.2 79.25 61.05 Q 76.9 62.45 73.95 64.7 L 72.05 66.25 71.75 66.55 71.4 66.8 69 69.05 Q 66.5 71.45 64.45 73.95 L 63.15 75.65 62.85 75.95 58.65 82.5 57.85 84.05 Q 57.25 85.3 57.1 85.65 L 56.35 87.25 53.3 97 52.1 106.35 52.1 107.2 52.05 107.6 52.2 114.4 53.95 124.7 55.65 129.95 56.2 131.25 Q 57 133.2 57.7 134.6 59.3 137.75 61.4 140.9 L 63.5 143.9 64.65 145.3 Q 65 145.8 65.8 146.7 L 65.95 146.85 66.7 147.75 66.85 147.9 67 148.1 70.75 151.85 Q 73.5 154.45 76.3 156.45 79.15 158.55 82.35 160.3 85.35 162 88.75 163.3 91.8 164.55 95.4 165.45 L 97.95 166.05 105.9 167.15 106.3 167.15 Q 106.6 167.2 107.2 167.2 L 107.6 167.25 108.95 167.3 Q 109 167.3 109.1 167.3 L 112.05 167.3 Q 112.6 167.3 112.85 167.25 L 114.9 167.2 115.3 167.15 Q 118.7 166.9 121.65 166.35 124.7 165.85 127.75 164.9 133.5 163.25 138.8 160.3 143.45 157.75 147.9 154.15 L 149.85 152.5 150.05 152.3 150.15 152.25 174.2 129.55 Q 176.6 127.25 176.7 123.95 176.8 120.65 174.5 118.2 172.2 115.8 168.9 115.7 165.6 115.6 163.2 117.9 M 163.35 84.75 L 162.85 85.2 126.25 124.9 126.05 125.05 126 125.15 124.15 126.9 Q 123.1 127.85 121.4 128.9 118.5 130.7 114.9 131.6 L 111.25 132.2 109.8 132.25 109.55 132.3 107.9 132.3 107.65 132.25 107.4 132.25 Q 103.45 132.1 100 130.7 96.45 129.4 93.3 126.75 L 92.5 126.1 92.15 125.75 92.05 125.7 90.35 124 87.9 120.85 Q 85.65 117.45 84.7 113.65 84.15 111.7 83.95 109.7 L 83.85 107.9 83.8 107.85 83.8 105.65 Q 83.95 101.55 85.2 97.95 86.5 94.25 88.75 91.15 L 90.75 88.7 90.85 88.6 90.85 88.55 91.3 88.1 91.4 88.05 91.55 87.85 93.6 85.95 93.95 85.7 Q 96.5 83.55 100.05 81.95 L 100.45 81.8 100.65 81.7 100.85 81.65 101.7 81.35 101.9 81.25 102.1 81.2 103.3 80.8 Q 105.1 80.3 106.55 80.1 L 109.8 79.8 Q 111.2 79.65 112.9 79.75 115.8 79.9 118.55 80.6 L 123.35 82.35 Q 123.6 82.45 125.35 83.4 L 127.1 84.5 Q 128.05 85.15 129.9 86.65 L 132.9 89.65 133.15 90 133.25 90.1 Q 133.35 90.2 133.4 90.1 133.5 90.05 133.4 89.95 L 133.3 89.85 133.05 89.5 130.3 86.25 Q 128.9 84.85 127.6 83.8 127.45 83.65 125.9 82.5 L 121.6 80.05 119.05 79 Q 115.95 78 113.1 77.65 111.25 77.4 109.75 77.4 107.85 77.3 106.25 77.45 104.3 77.6 102.6 77.95 L 100.75 78.35 99.85 78.65 99.6 78.7 98.9 78.95 Q 95.2 80.15 91.65 82.55 L 91.2 82.85 89.1 84.5 89 84.55 88.7 84.85 88.5 85 87.9 85.6 87.8 85.65 85.05 88.5 84.9 88.75 81.95 92.9 80.35 96 80.25 96.3 80.1 96.55 78.8 100.5 Q 78.2 102.8 77.9 105.25 L 77.75 107.75 77.7 107.9 77.7 110.1 Q 77.8 112.75 78.2 115.05 78.5 116.8 78.75 117.5 79.05 118.7 79.5 119.95 L 80.45 122.35 Q 81.25 124.1 81.6 124.65 82.25 125.9 82.95 126.85 83.45 127.65 84.45 128.95 L 84.85 129.45 Q 84.95 129.65 85.25 129.95 L 85.35 130.1 86.45 131.3 86.5 131.4 89.8 134.5 90.05 134.7 90.15 134.8 90.3 134.9 90.8 135.35 92.4 136.5 92.7 136.65 92.95 136.85 96.4 138.8 Q 98.95 140 101.35 140.7 103.05 141.2 103.9 141.35 L 106.5 141.8 106.65 141.8 106.8 141.85 107.15 141.85 107.8 141.95 108.1 141.95 108.25 142 109.7 142.05 110 142.1 114.25 142 Q 115.55 141.95 116.8 141.7 117.65 141.6 119.35 141.2 121.05 140.8 121.9 140.5 123.3 140.05 124.35 139.6 125.35 139.25 126.7 138.55 129.1 137.25 131.05 135.9 L 132.55 134.75 132.8 134.6 133.05 134.35 133.55 133.95 174.2 96.55 Q 176.65 94.3 176.75 90.95 176.9 87.65 174.65 85.2 172.4 82.75 169.1 82.65 165.8 82.5 163.35 84.75 M 162 53.35 L 162.3 53.6 167.75 59.35 168.25 60 168.45 60.2 Q 168.55 60.3 168.6 60.2 168.7 60.15 168.6 60.05 L 168.45 59.85 162.4 52.9 Q 160.05 50.45 157.35 48.1 L 155.6 46.65 155.4 46.45 152.85 44.45 152.6 44.3 152.4 44.1 144.1 38.75 138.2 35.85 138.05 35.75 137.85 35.7 136.5 35.15 Q 133.9 34.05 130.85 33.05 L 119.85 30.45 114.75 29.8 114.3 29.8 114.1 29.75 113.85 29.75 113 29.65 Q 112.4 29.65 112.1 29.6 111.5 29.6 111.25 29.55 110.65 29.55 110.35 29.5 L 109.45 29.5 Q 109.15 29.45 108.55 29.45 L 107.65 29.45 Q 107.05 29.45 106.75 29.4 L 104 29.45 Q 96.2 29.6 88.9 31.25 85.15 32.05 81.15 33.35 77.25 34.65 73.55 36.35 65.8 39.95 59.05 45.15 L 58.15 45.8 52.35 50.75 46.95 56.3 41 63.8 40.7 64.25 Q 38 68.15 35.95 72.05 33.7 76.25 32.1 80.45 L 30.65 84.6 28.55 92.8 27 105.55 26.95 107.85 26.9 107.95 27.1 116.05 27.15 116.35 27.7 121.9 27.75 122.2 27.8 122.35 27.8 122.5 28.5 126.55 Q 29.4 131.25 30.9 135.65 L 32.95 141.2 33.05 141.3 38.9 152.55 Q 41.2 156.25 44.25 160.1 L 50.3 166.9 Q 53.45 170.15 56.85 173 60.35 175.9 64 178.35 67.75 180.9 71.55 182.85 75.95 185.05 79.4 186.35 83.35 187.9 87.45 188.95 94.8 190.95 103.35 191.6 L 105.8 191.7 106.05 191.75 107.15 191.75 107.6 191.8 110.95 191.8 Q 115.3 191.7 118.35 191.4 125.4 190.75 132.1 188.95 134.6 188.3 138.35 187 141.1 186 144.05 184.7 L 144.4 184.5 144.55 184.45 151.05 181.1 151.35 180.9 151.65 180.75 152.8 180.05 153.1 179.9 153.2 179.8 161.4 174.05 161.6 173.85 165.85 170.25 165.95 170.2 174.2 162.3 Q 176.55 159.95 176.65 156.65 176.7 153.35 174.4 150.95 172.1 148.6 168.8 148.5 165.5 148.45 163.1 150.75 L 162.85 150.95 155.4 158.75 155.35 158.85 151.65 162.25 151.5 162.35 145.25 167.15 145.1 167.25 145 167.3 144.8 167.45 143.85 168.05 Q 143.8 168.15 143.65 168.2 L 138.9 171 138.35 171.25 138.25 171.35 138.1 171.4 137.8 171.55 Q 136.2 172.4 133.2 173.65 130.7 174.65 128.2 175.45 122.45 177.25 116.8 178 113.5 178.4 110.55 178.55 L 109.75 178.6 Q 109.2 178.6 108.95 178.65 L 106.4 178.65 106.2 178.7 106.1 178.7 106 178.65 104 178.65 Q 96.8 178.4 90.4 177 83.35 175.45 76.75 172.35 73.15 170.65 70.1 168.8 67 166.9 63.75 164.45 60.55 161.95 57.75 159.3 L 57.4 158.95 57.3 158.9 52.2 153.5 Q 49.7 150.7 47.2 147.1 L 43.2 140.6 43 140.1 41.65 137.5 41.6 137.35 39.6 132.6 Q 38.15 128.9 37.15 124.65 L 37.05 124.4 36.35 121.05 36.35 120.95 36.3 120.8 35.55 115.85 35 106.8 35.2 100.45 36.1 93.05 37.55 86.6 37.6 86.5 37.6 86.35 38.55 83.35 38.6 83.1 38.7 82.85 Q 40.05 78.8 41.85 75.05 43.65 71.25 45.9 67.7 L 51.4 60.15 Q 51.6 59.85 51.75 59.75 L 56.6 54.35 62.25 49.2 Q 65.4 46.65 68.7 44.4 72.15 42.1 75.5 40.45 79.05 38.65 82.55 37.3 86.6 35.8 89.8 35 96.85 33.15 104.15 32.7 105.35 32.6 105.9 32.6 L 106.15 32.6 106.35 32.55 112 32.5 Q 112.25 32.55 112.85 32.55 113.4 32.55 113.7 32.6 L 113.9 32.6 123.05 33.55 123.25 33.6 123.45 33.6 130.25 35.1 Q 133.05 35.9 135.85 36.9 L 137.15 37.4 137.5 37.5 142.8 39.85 150.8 44.4 156.8 48.8 Q 159.65 51.1 162 53.35 Z"/>
               <Path Fill="#FFFF0000" Data="M 571.6 65.4 L 567.6 65.4 Q 563.3 65.4 563.3 69.75 L 563.3 152.9 Q 563.3 157.2 567.6 157.2 L 571.6 157.2 Q 575.8 157.2 575.8 152.9 L 575.8 125.95 Q 575.8 120.75 577.45 116.2 579.1 111.75 582.1 108.4 585.1 105.1 589 103.3 593.15 101.4 597.75 101.4 601.6 101.4 604.2 102.75 606.55 103.9 608 106.25 609.25 108.3 609.75 111.5 L 610.3 117.95 610.3 152.9 Q 610.3 157.2 614.55 157.2 L 618.6 157.2 Q 622.85 157.2 622.85 152.9 L 622.85 115.05 Q 622.85 108.75 621.5 104.05 620.1 99.3 617.4 96.2 614.6 93.05 610.35 91.45 606 89.85 600.25 89.85 595.55 89.85 591.3 91.3 587.45 92.65 584.1 95 581.15 97.15 578.85 99.9 576.8 102.35 575.7 104.95 L 575.45 104.95 Q 575.8 102.6 575.8 99.5 L 575.8 69.75 Q 575.8 65.4 571.6 65.4 M 552.75 96.9 Q 542.05 89.85 531.05 89.85 521.1 90.8 516.85 92.5 510.5 95.05 505.75 99.75 501.05 104.45 498.55 110.65 495.9 117.1 495.9 124.3 495.9 131.6 498.45 138.05 501 144.3 505.7 148.95 510.45 153.65 516.8 156.2 521.05 157.85 531.05 158.8 542.85 158.8 554.4 150.75 557.6 148.5 555.6 144.95 L 554.5 143.05 Q 552.3 139.5 548.65 141.85 539.85 147.85 531.9 147.85 526.95 147.85 522.6 146.05 518.4 144.25 515.3 141 512.15 137.85 510.5 133.5 508.8 129.15 508.8 124.2 508.8 119.2 510.45 114.8 512.15 110.6 515.2 107.45 518.35 104.25 522.5 102.55 526.75 100.75 531.65 100.75 538.6 100.75 546.3 105.7 550.05 107.9 552.25 104.7 L 553.5 102.75 Q 556.1 99.05 552.75 96.9 M 490.4 121.2 Q 490.4 114.3 488.55 108.6 486.65 102.8 483.1 98.65 479.4 94.4 474.2 92.2 468.8 89.85 462.1 89.85 455.1 89.85 449.05 92.35 443.05 94.75 438.6 99.25 434.1 103.8 431.7 110.1 429.2 116.65 429.2 124.3 429.2 131.55 431.75 137.9 434.2 144.2 438.85 148.8 443.55 153.6 449.9 156.1 454.1 157.85 464.05 158.8 474.6 158.8 486.25 151.75 489.7 149.7 487.55 146.05 L 486.4 144.05 Q 484.35 140.65 480.55 142.65 472 147.85 464.8 147.85 460.35 147.85 456.45 146.4 452.45 144.9 449.3 142.1 446.15 139.15 444.3 135.1 442.35 130.85 442.1 125.6 L 486 125.6 Q 490.4 125.6 490.4 121.2 M 467.9 100.85 Q 470.8 102 472.95 104.2 475.15 106.4 476.35 109.65 477.7 113.1 477.8 117.25 L 442.6 117.25 Q 443.25 113.2 445 109.9 446.7 106.65 449.25 104.4 451.8 102.1 455.05 100.95 458.2 99.75 461.85 99.75 465.15 99.75 467.9 100.85 M 409.6 77.65 Q 409.6 73.35 405.35 73.35 L 401.55 73.35 Q 397.3 73.35 397.3 77.65 L 397.3 92.05 392.6 92.05 Q 388.3 92.05 388.3 96.4 L 388.3 98.05 Q 388.3 102.35 392.5 102.35 L 397.05 102.35 397.05 133.5 Q 397.05 139.55 399 144.3 400.85 148.75 404.35 151.85 407.65 154.8 412.15 156.3 416.45 157.7 421.5 157.7 424.1 157.7 425.35 156.7 426.65 155.7 426.65 153.45 L 426.65 150.75 Q 426.65 148.45 425.7 147.55 424.65 146.6 422.1 146.4 417.05 146.05 414.05 143.55 412.05 141.85 410.9 139.1 409.6 136 409.6 131.6 L 409.6 102.35 421.15 102.35 Q 425.35 102.35 425.35 98.05 L 425.35 96.4 Q 425.35 92.05 421.05 92.05 L 409.6 92.05 409.6 77.65 M 359.25 92.2 Q 357 92.2 357 94.4 L 357 155 Q 357 157.2 359.25 157.2 L 360.25 157.2 Q 362.5 157.2 362.5 155 L 362.5 129.15 Q 362.5 123.55 363.8 118.1 365.15 112.3 367.75 107.9 370.55 103 374.4 100.35 378.75 97.4 383.95 97.4 386.8 97.4 386.8 95.2 L 386.8 94.05 Q 386.8 91.8 384.05 91.8 380.05 91.8 376.5 93.2 373.15 94.55 370.3 97.1 367.55 99.5 365.45 102.85 363.5 106.05 362.2 109.9 L 361.95 109.9 Q 362.5 107.55 362.5 104.6 L 362.5 94.4 Q 362.5 92.2 360.25 92.2 L 359.25 92.2 M 340.35 111.05 Q 337.8 104.95 333.15 100.4 328.5 95.75 322.45 93.2 316.2 90.6 309.35 90.6 302.5 90.6 296.2 93.2 290.2 95.75 285.55 100.4 280.85 104.95 278.3 111.05 275.65 117.35 275.65 124.3 275.65 131.45 278.3 137.85 280.85 144.05 285.55 148.8 290.2 153.5 296.2 156.1 302.5 158.8 309.35 158.8 316.2 158.8 322.45 156.1 328.45 153.5 333.15 148.8 337.8 144.05 340.35 137.85 343 131.45 343 124.3 343 117.35 340.35 111.05 M 329.1 104.05 Q 332.95 108 335.05 113.1 337.3 118.35 337.3 124.3 337.3 130.4 335.05 135.8 332.95 141.1 329.1 145.1 325.3 149 320.2 151.25 315.05 153.45 309.35 153.45 303.65 153.45 298.45 151.25 293.4 149 289.55 145.1 285.65 141.1 283.6 135.8 281.35 130.4 281.35 124.3 281.35 118.35 283.6 113.1 285.65 108 289.55 104.05 293.4 100.25 298.45 98.1 303.65 95.95 309.35 95.95 315.05 95.95 320.2 98.1 325.3 100.25 329.1 104.05 M 276.7 66.15 Q 274.75 66.15 274.25 68 L 247.35 139.8 Q 245.75 144.05 243.8 150.75 L 243.55 150.75 Q 241.65 144.05 240.05 139.8 L 213.25 68 Q 212.7 66.15 210.8 66.15 L 209.4 66.15 Q 206.65 66.15 207.55 68.8 L 240.05 155.35 Q 240.6 157.2 242.55 157.2 L 245 157.2 Q 246.9 157.2 247.5 155.35 L 280 68.8 Q 280.8 66.15 278.15 66.15 L 276.7 66.15 Z"/>
            </Canvas>

         </ControlTemplate>
      </Setter.Value>
   </Setter>
</Style>
```

So now we have a clean resource, let's use it, I did change the `Fill` color to be able to see it on a white background though. So for the instance level;

```
<ContentControl Style="{StaticResource svgLogo}"/>
```

You should be able to see what you expect now. Keep in mind that SVG and WPF XAML [Path Markup Syntax](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms752293(v=vs.110).aspx) are very similar, but are not entirely the same. Personally I usually use Mike Swanson's [ai to xaml](http://www.mikeswanson.com/xamlexport/) plugin for Adobe Illustrator. It's super useful and he's an awesome guy.

Anyhow, now we've got your logo, so how about that weird error? I see this in there but I don't see where/how it is used `<Style x:Key="VortechLogo" BasedOn="{x:Null}" TargetType="{x:Type TextBox}">` which would be the only TargetType of `TextBox` I see so let's start there, if you omit that style, do you get the same error?

In that scenario I'm not sure what that `TextBox` style is doing. I don't see it's `ControlTemplate` which would have a Content Host part and `BasedOn="{x:Null}" is redundant and can be removed since it's explicitly named with an x:Key name.

So I would probably need to see more to troubleshoot your TextBox error, but at least your ContentControl logo should be sorted. Let me know what else you bump into while debugging and we'll see if we can't get it fixed too. Hope this helps, cheers. :)

Comment: first off I would like to give you a huge thanks for your effort in helping me out. as you probably can tell, I'm very new to xaml and didn't quite grasp it fully yet. 

it works now. I have absolutely no clue why the text box style was in there but it definitely explains it, since VortechLogo was the original name that I used. I removed it and implemented your solution and it works beautifully. thank you very much you're a champ.

sadly I can't upvote you because I don't have enough rep but know that I would!
now I'll check out what stuff you scraped off in detail for the future :)

Comment: however the image doesn't render at runtime but I'm sure I'll find a fix quick enough (btw my background was a light shade of grey so I should have seen it :D but kudos for thinking of that)

Comment: No worries, we've all been there. If it's not showing at runtime and the usage is like you show in your example then it may not be getting the space it needs from it's parent container Grid. XAML has its quirks but I still prefer it over html personally even though I have to work with both heavily often. If you still run into issues we'll get you sorted.

Comment: playing around with spacing fixed it, it really does seem to have not gotten the space it needed. yeah xaml definitely has its quirks haha :D but I agree, I'll take it over html any day. I'm curious to learn more as I go through with this project, thanks for all of your help man. really appreciate it!