# importing vector image (XAML file) into WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, image, xaml

**EDIT**

When using files for programming they need to be in the same file directory as the code so you can reference then. This is why there is normally a resource folder when ever you create a new project. From there you can import it into your project and use it(look at answer bellow on how to do that).

**set up**

I've created a vector image with a xaml file format. I used Microsoft expression design 4 and follow the guide from this question: [Best way to use a vector image in WPF?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13292179/best-way-to-use-a-vector-image-in-wpf) This was good and allowed me to make my image however when it creates the file type it turned it into window markup file(I'm telling you this just in case this is a problem but this isn't the question). I don't fully understand what The code in the question is doing and they said they could just drag and drop the xaml file into the window, When I tried that method all I get is errors.

**problem**

Now that I have my image that I want to use and import into my WPF file. Preferably I would like to import it directly into my grid that I have on my windows(This is just the default set up that you get when you open a new WPF) but I also looked at using a image box(I don't know if you can use XAML in image box so I don't know if that's possible). With both attempts I had no success. So I don't know if has something to do with the file and not importing it right or that I need a subroutine to load it into.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you have there is a ResourceDictonary with a `DrawingBrush`, which would be imported like this (provided that the file is part of your Visual Studio project and its Build Action is set to `Page`):

```
<Window.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary>
        <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
            <ResourceDictionary Source="And gate.xaml"/>
        </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
    </ResourceDictionary>
</Window.Resources>
```

and used as `Background` of a UI element or `Fill` of a Rectangle:

```
<Rectangle Width="100" Height="100" 
           Fill="{StaticResource UnnamedObject0}"/>
```

Note that a simple Path like

```
<Window.Resources>
    <Geometry x:Key="AndGate">M0,2 L5,2 A3,3 1 1 1 5,8 L0,8Z</Geometry>
</Window.Resources>

<Path Width="100" Height="100" Stretch="Uniform" Stroke="Black" StrokeThickness="2"
      Data="{StaticResource AndGate}"/>
```

would generate a similar output.

You may want to take a look at [Shapes and Basic Drawing in WPF Overview](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wpf/graphics-multimedia/shapes-and-basic-drawing-in-wpf-overview).

Comment: The file isn't stored as a part of visual studios. That's why I assume I'm getting the error: Exception: An error occurred while finding the resource dictionary. Thanks for quick reply and answer. Didn't think about rectangle.

Comment: Then just add it. Or forget about Expression Design and declare simple shapes as Path elements (where the Geometry assigned to the Data property may also be stored as XAML resource).

Comment: would the file being on one drive affect it? This is the file location:<ResourceDictionary Source="C:\Users\andre\OneDrive\Documents\school\computing\Course work\And gate.xaml"/>

Comment: It should be part of the project, or that of a referenced assembly.

Comment: I need to keep the images separate from something like canvas as later on i'm going to drag and drop them. from what people have told me is that when you do that the computer tries to render the image each time the mouse moves and it lags horribly.

Comment: I'm sorry I don't quite understand. What do you mean by part of the project? does the files have to be in where the source code is kept? In this general vicinity?    C:\Users\andre\OneDrive\Documents\Visual Studio 2017\Projects

Comment: Part of the project means add the file to the project, just like a source file.

Comment: If it were me, for such a simple shape, create a single path, and do like his last example .... and hi, I answered your mentioned question but you can practically always count on Clemens to steer you on a right track.

Comment: Thank you!  Finally got it to work. Hope I wasn't too much of a idiot for you it's just that I haven't done anything other than console applications. Thanks!

Comment: WPF is nothing you can start without preparation. IMO it is required to read some introductory material, e.g. a book like Adam Nathan's *WPF Unleashed*.